# git: difference between "branchname" and "refs/heads/branchname"

Tags: git

Best to be explained at an example: I am on branch 0.58 of repository and this his how I pull:

```
git pull origin 0.58
```

When I just call "git pull", I get:

```
ip238:openlierox az$ git pull
You asked me to pull without telling me which branch you
want to merge with, and 'branch.0.58.merge' in
your configuration file does not tell me either.  Please
name which branch you want to merge on the command line and
try again (e.g. 'git pull <repository> <refspec>').
See git-pull(1) for details on the refspec.

If you often merge with the same branch, you may want to
configure the following variables in your configuration
file:

    branch.0.58.remote = <nickname>
    branch.0.58.merge = <remote-ref>
    remote.<nickname>.url = <url>
    remote.<nickname>.fetch = <refspec>

See git-config(1) for details.
```

Seems I probably forgot some option (--track ?) when I checked that branch out. Anyway, I have set this now:

```
git config branch.0.58.merge 0.58
git config branch.0.58.remote origin
```

And this seems to work. Then, just because of interest, I took a look at some other branch about these setting:

```
ip238:openlierox az$ git config branch.0.57.merge
refs/heads/0.57
ip238:openlierox az$ git config branch.0.57.remote
origin
```

I was wondering now, is there a difference between "0.58" or should I specify "refs/heads/0.58"?

What is the difference exactly?

Comment: Just to adress the typo in the title *(without messing with an old title by modifying it now)*, it should read **"refs/heads/branchname"**, `heads` with an "s".

Answer (score 191, accepted):

A `ref` is anything pointing to a commit, for example, branches (heads), tags, and remote branches. You should see heads, remotes, and tags in your `.git/refs` directory, assuming you have all three types of refs in your repository.

`refs/heads/0.58` specifies a *branch* named 0.58. If you don't specify what namespace the ref is in, git will look in the default ones. This makes using only 0.58 conceivably ambiguous - you could have both a branch and a tag named 0.58.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this explains it very well. It just worked with the simple "0.58" as there is no such named tag.

Comment: Right, it will essentially always be completely fine, but it's good to be safe.

Comment: Here's all of them for clarity: `refs/heads/` and `refs/remotes/` and `refs/tags/`

Comment: If anyone is confused what "branches (heads)" as I was - head vs HEAD explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4381549/8888320

Answer (score 58):

Just for somebody who is curious -  [`git show-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-ref), which is available since Git v1.8.2.2, will show you all references you have in your local repository.

Comment: Also `git log --decorate=full` will show the full names of references in the history

Answer (score 41):

See, `branchName` needs to be fully resolved before GIT can actually identify it. The fully resolved name will be `refs/heads/branchName`.

One of the famous commands`git checkout branchName` actually automatically resolves it fully to identify where you want to checkout. Note that it does it automatically hence we never write it fully on our own.

How does it do that ?
Let us look [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)

> **refname** :, e.g. `master`, `heads/master`, `refs/heads/master`
>
> A symbolic ref name. E.g. master typically means the commit object
>   referenced by `refs/heads/master`. If you happen to have both
>   `heads/master` and `tags/master`, you can explicitly say `heads/master` to
>   tell Git which one you mean. When ambiguous, a `<refname>` is
>   disambiguated by taking the first match in the following rules:
>
> 1.If `$GIT_DIR/<refname>` exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and
>   `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
>
> 2.otherwise, `refs/<refname>` if it exists;
>
> 3.otherwise, `refs/tags/<refname>` if it exists;
>
> 4.otherwise, `refs/heads/<refname>` if it exists;
>
> 5.otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>` if it exists;
>
> 6.otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

So by above 6 steps , it tries to resolve what is this `branchName`. Hence we never need to give a fully resolved branchName to it.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006786/why-is-there-a-difference-between-master-and-heads-master) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054148/why-does-git-checkout-with-explicit-refs-heads-branch-give-detached-head/21055585#comment87399506_21055585) too.

Also, go in your `.git` directory and see inside the `ref` folder.

Answer (score 2):

The other difference is:

- `branchname` (like `--no-all` or `--no-remote`) can represent an "invalid type" ref: `git branch --no-all` or `git branch --no-remotes` look like a legitimate option, but they are not. And it is then interpreted by Git as a "branch name".
- `refs/heads/branchname` is immediately seen as invalid with those non-existent options (`refs/heads/--no-all` or `refs/heads/--no-remotes`: makes no sense)

With Git 2.42 (Q3 2023), the command line parser rejects those as invalid *options*, not "invalid branch name".

See [commit e12cb98](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e12cb98e1e083c23a03fcfabb3a3c6a5a22ce3c5) (18 Jul 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9a5e3b5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a5e3b5f47098221023131c4e31cb53295211b5f), 26 Jul 2023)</sup>

> ### [`branch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e12cb98e1e083c23a03fcfabb3a3c6a5a22ce3c5): reject "`--no-all`" and "`--no-remotes`" early

> As the command line parser for "[`git branch --all`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e12cb98e1e083c23a03fcfabb3a3c6a5a22ce3c5/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L177)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---all))</sup> forgets to use `PARSE_OPT_NONEG,` it accepted "[`git branch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e12cb98e1e083c23a03fcfabb3a3c6a5a22ce3c5/Documentation/git-branch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch))</sup> `--no-all`, and then passed a nonsense value to the underlying machinery, leading to a fatal error "`filter_refs: invalid type`".
> The "`--remotes`" option had exactly the same issue.
>
> Catch the unsupported options early in the option parser.

The error message will be:

```
unknown option --no-all
unknown option --no-remotes
```

(Instead of "`filter_refs: invalid type`")

Answer (score 0):

Consider "branchname" is Harry,
Then

Harry is a pointer which is simply used to point the latest commit of that branch.

Whereas refs/heads/Harry is a kind of history tracker which tracks each and every activity done using the Harry pointer.It can be any activity like commit,switching to other branch,pushing the content of branch etc.