# What is HEAD in Git?

Tags: git

You see the Git documentation saying things like

> The branch must be fully merged in HEAD.

But what is Git `HEAD` exactly?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git/967611#967611

Comment: Also see [how to undo multiple commits using HEAD, or how to checkout to multiple commits before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46350644/5175709)

Comment: Curious that there's practically a 1:1 correspondence between 'heads' and (named) 'branches' (see [`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote) as evidence) and yet the definition of 'HEAD' seems so hard to pin down. The documentation for [git branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) says simply that `HEAD` is, in effect, "the tip of the current branch". All the confusion must actually be about the definition of a branch -- which is surprisingly nuanced: [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/86967)

Comment: _HEAD names the commit on which you based the changes in the working tree_ source: [gitrevisions manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)

Answer (score 973, accepted):

You can think of the HEAD as the "current branch". When you switch branches with `git checkout`, the HEAD revision changes to point to the tip of the new branch.

You can see what HEAD points to by doing:

```
cat .git/HEAD
```

In my case, the output is:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

It is possible for HEAD to refer to a specific revision that is not associated with a branch name. This situation is called a [detached HEAD](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head).

Comment: So git HEAD is context dependent on which BRANCH you are on, correct?  Even further, __you__ as a developer?  I guess I'm asking, Is Git HEAD going to be a repository-wide global thing, or individual for each dev?

Comment: @bobobobo: That's right, HEAD is like a pointer that points to the current branch. When you checkout a different branch, HEAD changes to point to the new one. The current HEAD is local to each repository, and is therefore individual for each developer.

Comment: So this should also explains why when one pushes revisions to a remote "central" repository, which doesn't have HEAD since it doesn't have a checked out working copy, he typically push the HEAD of the local repository to the master branch of the remote repository, right?

Comment: I feel the ideas explained in this thread can be better illustrated by a graph of some sort ... any one?

Comment: Besides `HEAD` being the current branch, **must it be the last commit** in the current branch?

Comment: @動靜能量: HEAD can point to *any* commit, it does not need to be the last commit in any branch. (When HEAD points to a commit that is not the last commit in a branch, that is a "detached HEAD").

Comment: @GregHewgill This question should be updated to say "You can think of the HEAD as the 'current commit'" rather than the "current branch". This defition confused me when I found that during an interactive rebase with many commits, git updates `HEAD` but not the branch (as evidenced by `git reset --hard branchname`). It also explains why `git reflog HEAD` shows you all steps during rebases that contain many commits, whereas `git reflog branchname` shows you only one commit for the rebase.

Comment: Git HEAD is a pointer to a given commit, just like branch names, the only difference being that while branch names are conceptually meant to point to the latest commit in a branch, a HEAD can be used to hop between commits either within the same branch or across branches.

You may also try to visualize HEAD as a mouse pointer, that lets you select a commit that you want to check out.

Comment: HEAD is *not* "the current branch".  Is is the name given to the commit from which the working tree's current state was initialized.  In more practical terms, it can be thought of as a symbolic reference to the checked-out commit.

Comment: @BenCollins Thank you.  It's unfortunate that the accepted answer (above) gives an incorrect answer.

Comment: @BenCollins Quoting from [Git Branching - What a Branch Is](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is), concerning `HEAD`: _"In Git, this is a pointer to the local branch you’re currently on."_ Further, note that a branch itself is but a pointer. Quoting from the same source: _"A branch in Git is simply a lightweight movable pointer to [a commit]. (...) A branch in Git is in actuality a simple file that contains the 40 character SHA-1 checksum of the commit it points to."_ So I think the accepted answer is fine. Yours is also. Where's the difference?

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa the difference is that one doesn't have to be on a branch at all.  The working copy can come from any commit, regardless of what branch you were on, in which case you'd be on a detached head.

Comment: @BenCollins I agree, detached heads are a special case, but that case is also mentioned in the accepted answer. My point being, the accepted answer is perfectly fine. :)

Comment: Voted down. I agree with @BenCollins. In my opinion the first sentence is quite confusing, and could be rephrased to: "You can think of the HEAD as the current commit on the current branch"

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1 - Absolutely.Also voted down. Git is complex enough to accept as correct some wrong answers.

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1: how does "You can think of the HEAD as the current commit on the current branch" make any sense, given that a branch is a pointer / symbolic reference to an arbitrary commit?  Are you using the word "branch" in the sense of some other VCS?

Comment: @DonHatch "given that a branch is a pointer / symbolic reference to an arbitrary commit" hmmm I would say that, at least for me, for my understanding, it makes more sense for a branch to be a collection of commits, an array of commits. Then you have a pointer to this array, and a name, and more stuff, this results in a branch. Then you can navigate through this array (read through this branch), between different commits, by using the HEAD pointer, which points to the current commit, on the current branch (move it backwards with checkout and #SHA1, move one forwards with commit)

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1: everything you say makes sense to me, but it is terminology used by other VCSs; git does not think that way, and in git terminology "branch" does not mean all the meaningful things you listed; it just means a reference to a commit.   I *wish* git thought in the sensible way you are describing-- in my experience git makes it essentially impossible to examine the array of commits of which you speak-- it just doesn't remember that information.  To me, this is a really serious failing of git.

Comment: @DonHatch, perhaps you should learn to use the options of `git log` better.  You can indeed view all the parent and ancestor commits of any given commit, and the options for sifting through this data to get what you need are powerful in the extreme.

Comment: @Wildcard - glad you're so happy with it, but despite all the powerful-in-the-extreme features of which you speak, it's lacking basic information that I, and many others, find indispensible. Take a look at the famous diagram on this page:  http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ . The style is often called "swim lanes" .  Can you get such a drawing out of git?  You definitely cannot; there's plenty of discussion of this fact around the web.  That fact alone makes it difficult for many people coming from a perforce background to see git as a serious option.

Comment: @DonHatch, I thought "Git Flow" looked like a great branching model until I read ["Git Flow Considered Harmful"](http://endoflineblog.com/gitflow-considered-harmful) and the [follow-up post](http://endoflineblog.com/follow-up-to-gitflow-considered-harmful).  I find that workflow much more workable, personally.

Comment: @Wildcard - Thanks for the pointers.  To be clear, I didn't mean to be advocating GitFlow (I guess that's the model being discussed in the article); I haven't looked at it too closely, nor at alternatives.   But I'm definitely a big fan of diagrams with robust swim lanes, of which the diagrams in that article are a really good example, independent of the article's viewpoint.  Using GitFlow or not, you can't make such diagrams out of the info that's normally in git.

Comment: Is a revision a commit?

Comment: Aside from `master` which is obvious. Can you explain what does `ref: refs/heads/master` refer to? Do we have multiple heads?

Comment: You can use `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` to output what branch HEAD is pointing at which is pretty useful to confirm whether or not you're in detached HEAD state or not

Comment: @BenCollins re `HEAD` is not the current branch, it is symbolic reference to the checked-out commit: in truth it is typically neither. It is a symbolic reference to whatever you've checked out. If it is a commit, yes, it points to the commit, but typically it is not. Similarly, OP, `HEAD` can refer to a commit that is associated with a branch name **and still be detached**. `HEAD` is only attached if it is **not** pointing to a commit, but rather to a branch. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54935492/7936744)

Comment: Just to hammer it home: Greg (OP), re: "(When HEAD points to a commit that is not the last commit in a branch, that is a "detached HEAD")." Nope. If `HEAD` points directly to a commit, no matter what commit that is (even if it is the last commit in a branch), it is detached.

Comment: @BenCollins "[HEAD] is the name given to the commit from which the working tree's current state was initialized." Not necessarily. It's typically true, but not always. For example, after `git reset --soft <commit>` can point HEAD to a completely different snapshot, but doesn't change the state of the working tree. Or after a `git commit`, it would be more accurate to say the HEAD commit was initialized (indirectly) from the working tree's current state rather than vice versa.

Comment: HEAD is just a pointer to commit id that you have checked out recently. If HEAD is on some older commit ids which are not referenced by name(say-branch/tag) then it is said to be in 'detached HEAD' state.

Comment: I would love to see the uses of HEAD enlisted. I've always done `git clone ... && git remote set-head origin -d` so I never see this HEAD*! It's just an eyesore that keeps coming in the way when looking at the branch names in the commit history.  
*Of course, when I checkout a commit no branch is on, this detatched HEAD appears which is useful and then disappears the moment I'm back to the branch. Yet to learn about other conveniences of having HEAD around all the time.

Comment: @trss it is mostly used as a "current branch" shortcut, "diff last 2 commits in my current branch" would be `git diff HEAD~2`. If you want to check out two commits back you don't need to `git log`, find the hash and `git checkout <found sha>` but only `git checkout HEAD~2` (which will also put you in 'detached HEAD' as well).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the commands referencing HEAD. Since they happen to work even when `git remote set-head origin -d` has made it disappear, I'm yet to see any other convenience of having the HEAD around all the time.

Comment: The command `cat .git/HEAD` works fine in Unix/Linux/PowerShell. In a Windows command prompt you can use `type .git\HEAD` instead.

Comment: What else could be in this file? Are you curious to see other options? Is the commit hash to be the SIGN for understanding the HEAD is detached?
I will not spoil it - try to write in this file `ref: refs/tags/tag-name` and see what happens in `git status` and what happens with the new commit.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff states at several points that HEAD is basically "latest commit". All this nitpicking is useless, just like saying that dogs do not have 4 legs, because dogs with 3 or even 5 legs exist. In other words "the answer is technically correct, but useless". Comparing with HEAD compares with a specific commit (or maybe some other state), the fact that the .git/HEAD file only stores the branch name is irrelevant.

Answer (score 238):

To quote [other people](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/%7Ecduan/technical/git/git-1.shtml#heads):

> A head is simply a reference to a
> commit object. Each head has a name
> (branch name or tag name, etc). By
> default, there is a head in every
> repository called master. A repository
> can contain any number of heads. At
> any given time, one head is selected
> as the “current head.” This head is
> aliased to HEAD, always in capitals".
>
> Note this difference: a “head”
> (lowercase) refers to any one of the
> named heads in the repository; “HEAD”
> (uppercase) refers exclusively to the
> currently active head. This
> distinction is used frequently in Git
> documentation.

Another good source that quickly covers the inner workings of git (and therefore a better understanding of heads/HEAD) can be found [here](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/).  References (ref:) or heads or branches can be considered like post-it notes stuck onto commits in the commit history.  Usually they point to the tip of series of commits, but they can be moved around with [`git checkout`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-checkout) or [`git reset`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html) etc.

Comment: From this: "Each head has a name". And  "one head is selected as the “current head.” This head is aliased to HEAD".

So i conclude from this that "HEAD" does not refer to situation of "detached HEAD" state.

Comment: @gxyd if it is the case that HEAD doesn't point to a 'head', it is a detached HEAD. It is pointing at the commit id of the commit you have specified (using, for example, `git checkout HEAD~2`), which is not the commit id of a known head. See the article at http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/ for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: @Silfheed: Generally I think this answer is conceptually more sound than the accepted one (even though using lowercase "head" to refer to a branch confuses many people). However `git revert` isn't a good example of moving a branch to not be at the tip, because `git revert` just creates some new commits and still leaves the current branch at the (new) tip.

Comment: "which is not the commit id of a known head" - Actually, a detached HEAD *can* be pointing at a commit ID which is also the commit ID of a known head (or several heads). What makes it detached is that the HEAD is pointing directly to the commit ID, not to a head. This will affect the behavior of future `commit`s, `reset`s, etc.

Comment: @LarsH: Good point on a detached HEAD pointing at a commit ID instead of a reference. You can actually verify this by looking at .git/HEAD. If it is detached, it will contain the hash of a commit, even if it's the same commit as a known head. If it is attached, it will contain the path to the head (ie 'ref: refs/heads/bob'). As for the revert command, after 8 years I never caught that typo. Git reset is what allows you to adjust a particular head to point to a particular commit.

Comment: This answer is useful in noting the difference between _HEAD_ and _head_ but otherwise I find it a bit confusing. `HEAD` is simply a reference to a commit that will be the parent of the next commit you're going to create.

Answer (score 157):

There is a, perhaps subtle, but important misconception in a number these answers. I thought I'd add my answer to clear it up.

> What is `HEAD`?

#### HEAD is YOU

`HEAD`is a symbolic reference pointing to wherever you are in your commit history. It follows you wherever you go, whatever you do, like a shadow. If you make a commit, `HEAD` will move. If you checkout something, `HEAD` will move. Whatever you do, if you have moved somewhere new in your commit history, `HEAD` has moved along with you. To address one common misconception: you cannot detach yourself from `HEAD`. That is not what a detached HEAD state is. If you ever find yourself thinking: "oh no, i'm in detached HEAD state! I've lost my HEAD!" Remember, it's your HEAD. HEAD is you. You haven't detached from the HEAD, you and your HEAD have detached from something else.

#### What can HEAD attach to?

`HEAD` can point to a commit, yes, but typically it does not. Let me say that again. *Typically `HEAD` does not point to a commit.* It points to a branch reference. It is *attached* to that branch, and when you do certain things (e.g., `commit` or [`reset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934887/7936744)), the attached branch will move along with `HEAD`. You can see what it is pointing to by looking under the hood.

```
cat .git/HEAD
```

Normally you'll get something like this:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

Sometimes you'll get something like this:

```
a3c485d9688e3c6bc14b06ca1529f0e78edd3f86
```

That's what happens when `HEAD` points directly to a commit. This is called a detached HEAD, because `HEAD` is pointing to something other than a branch reference. If you make a commit in this state, `master`, no longer being attached to `HEAD`, will no longer move along with you. It does not matter where that commit is. **You could be on the same commit as your master branch,  but if `HEAD` is pointing to the commit rather than the branch, it is detached and a new commit will not be associated with a branch reference.**

You can look at this graphically if you try the following exercise. From a git repository, run this. You'll get something slightly different, but they key bits will be there. When it is time to checkout the commit directly, just use whatever abbreviated hash you get from the first output (here it is `a3c485d`).

```
git checkout master
git log --pretty=format:"%h:  %d" -1
# a3c485d:   (HEAD -> master)

git checkout a3c485d -q # (-q is for dramatic effect)
git log --pretty=format:"%h:  %d" -1   
# a3c485d:   (HEAD, master)
```

OK, so there is a small difference in the output here. Checking out the commit directly (instead of the branch) gives us a comma instead of an arrow. What do you think, are we in a detached HEAD state? HEAD is still referring to a specific revision that is associated with a branch name. We're still *on* the master branch, aren't we?

Now try:

```
git status
# HEAD detached at a3c485d
```

Nope. We're in 'detached HEAD' state.

You can see the same representation of `(HEAD -> branch)` vs. `(HEAD, branch)` with `git log -1`.

#### In conclusion

`HEAD` is you. It points to whatever you checked out, wherever you are. Typically that is not a commit, it is a branch. If `HEAD` *does* point to a commit (or tag), even if it's the same commit (or tag) that a branch also points to, you (and `HEAD`) have been detached from that branch. Since you don't have a branch attached to you, the branch won't follow along with you as you make new commits. `HEAD`, however, will.

Comment: I like this answer, because while the documentation describes truth, the software defines truth. `.git/HEAD` is what the software considers to be HEAD.

Comment: For its conceptual definition alone, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I really think this is the best answer. The others imply that `HEAD` is the tip of a branch, but it is not, it is like a tape head. A really easy way to see this in action is `git checkout HEAD~1` to go back one commit, then `git checkout HEAD~1` to go back another commit.

If `HEAD` always referred to the most recent commit on a branch the second command would be the same as the first - it is not. The second command moves your `HEAD` back one more time, i.e. you are now two commits from the tip of the branch. It's subtle but important.

Comment: I liked your expression "HEAD is YOU".

Comment: This answer should be accepted, it's well explained!

Comment: It's correct to say that it refers to the latest commit on your current branch, by default.

Answer (score 81):

HEAD is just a special pointer that points to the local branch you’re currently on.

From the [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) book, chapter [3.1 Git Branching - Branches in a Nutshell](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell), in the section **Creating a New Branch**:

> What happens if you create a new branch? Well, doing so creates a new
>   pointer for you to move around. Let’s say you create a new branch
>   called testing. You do this with the git branch command:
>
> ```
> $ git branch testing
> ```
>
> This creates a new pointer at the same commit you’re currently on
>
> [image]
>
> How does Git know what branch you’re currently on? It keeps a special pointer called HEAD. Note that this is a lot different than
>   the concept of HEAD in other VCSs you may be used to, such as
>   Subversion or CVS. In Git, this is a pointer to the local branch
>   you’re currently on. In this case, you’re still on master. The git
>   branch command only created a new branch — it didn’t switch to that
>   branch.
>
> [image]

Comment: Nice, could use a picture showing the detached HEAD case though

Comment: @DonHatch, Good explanation of detached HEAD http://stackoverflow.com/a/35301963/1074179

Comment: Nice answer. Branches are nothing but labeled commits, when you make new commits , this label is moved to the new new commit. When you checkout a commit that doesn't have a label , it's in detached HEAD state. That means HEAD is pointing to a commit that doesn't have a branch label. If you checkout `34ac2` in above example, now HEAD would be pointing to that commit and it's called a detached HEAD. In this state, you can make changes, experiment, and commit changes too, but once you checkout a different branch, you'd lose all your changes, unless of course you create a new branch.

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx but you can checkout a commit that has a branch label and still be in detached head state because your HEAD is no longer pointing to the branch label but the branch's commit id

Comment: @Marc when you checkout a commit that has a branch label (in other words a branch), HEAD moves with you. It won't be pointing to somewhere else. So, in this case, you won't be in the detached state.

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx I think we're talking about semantics at this point.  You are correct a branch label is a text reference to a particular commit.  It is, however, not a commit. So if you did a `git log` and got something like `commit ad0265... HEAD -> foo ...` that would mean the `foo` branch is a reference to commit id `ad0265`.  Doing a checkout of the text reference `foo` is not a detached head.  Doing a checkout of the commit id `ad0265` would result in a detached head.  May be I'm missing some subtlety of what you're communicating. I hope this wall of text helps discover where I'm lost.

Comment: @Marc I think now I get what you meant. What you said is true. And when you checkout a single commit (whether or not it has a branch label) you're no longer in a branch. Because of this, your branch label doesn't move forward with your next commits. That's why it's still in detached state.

Comment: @RukshanMarapana "but once you checkout a different branch, you'd lose all your changes, unless of course you create a new branch" That's not super accurate. If you don't commit it, then it would just be another commit in git. But it won't be labeled with a branch. You can later retrieve that commit through `git reflog`, but it's super difficult, because you have to know the SHA of the commit.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say “if you commit it”

Comment: @mfaani, you can edit your comments.

Answer (score 68):

I recommend this definition from github developer Scott Chacon [[video reference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ZDR433b0HJY#t=2791s)]:

> Head is your current branch.  It is a symbolic reference.  It is a reference to a branch.  You always have HEAD, but HEAD will be pointing to one of these other pointers, to one of the branches that you're on.  It is the parent of your next commit.  It is what should be what was last checked-out into your working directory... This is the last known state of what your working directory was.

The whole video will give a fair introduction to the whole git system so I also recommend you to watch it all if have the time to.

Comment: So the true def is "the parent of your next commit"

Comment: and also "the thing pointing at the next branch that will move"

Comment: @nicolas - I don't *think* that is true. HEAD can point at any commit, it does not necessarily have to point at a branch - when it does not, you are in "detached HEAD" mode.

Comment: It can point to any commit indeed, but that does not define what it is. afaik what was written in jan is its definition

Comment: The video is great, but unfortunately, it makes an ill-suited answer for Stack Overflow. What if the video is taken down sometime in the future? Then your link will point to nothing. A better answer would include a transcript of what Scott says in the video.

Comment: Scott says HEAD is a pointer to a branch.  But HEAD can point to old commits too.  This is sooo confusing.

Comment: Nice to see a reference, but the answer is nowhere to be found in your answer. :P

Answer (score 47):

Assuming it is not a special case called "detached HEAD", then, as stated in the O'Reilly Git book, 2nd edtion, p.69, `HEAD` means:

> `HEAD` always refers to the most recent commit on the current
>   branch. When you change branches, `HEAD` is updated to refer to the new
>   branch’s latest commit.

so

> `HEAD` is **the "tip" of the current branch**.

Note that we can use `HEAD` to refer to the most recent commit, and use `HEAD~` as the commit before the tip, and `HEAD~~` or `HEAD~2` as the commit even earlier, and so forth.

Answer (score 29):

`HEAD` refers to the current commit that your working copy points to, i.e. the commit you currently have checked-out.  From the [official Linux Kernel documentation on specifying Git revisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions):

> `HEAD` names the commit on which you based the changes in the working tree.

Note, however, that in the upcoming version 1.8.4 of Git, `@` can also be used as a shorthand for `HEAD`, as [noted by Git contributor Junio C Hamano in his Git Blame blog](http://git-blame.blogspot.com/2013/07/git-184-rc0.html):

> Instead of typing "HEAD", you can say "@" instead, e.g. "git log @".

Stack Overflow user [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) also found some [interesting information on why `@` was chosen as a shorthand in his answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git/964927#964927).

Also of interest, in some environments it's not necessary to capitalize `HEAD`, specifically in operating systems that use case-insensitive file systems, specifically Windows and OS X.

Answer (score 24):

Take a look at [Creating and playing with branches](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906140534/http://www.gitguys.com/topics/creating-and-playing-with-branches/)

HEAD is actually a file whose contents determines where the HEAD variable refers:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
$ cat .git/refs/heads/master
35ede5c916f88d8ba5a9dd6afd69fcaf773f70ed
```

In this repository, the contents of the HEAD file refers to a second file named **refs/heads/master**. The file **refs/heads/master** contains the hash of the most recent commit on the master branch.

The result is HEAD points to the master branch commit from the **.git/refs/heads/master** file.

[image]

Answer (score 22):

#### *What is HEAD in Git? (conceptually)*

`HEAD` is a pointer to the currently checked out branch or commit, it answers the question: ***Where am I right now in the repository?*** Or, in other words, it's Git's way of knowing on which commit to mirror your local Working Tree on, and whether you're currently working on a branch (*attached*) or not (*detached*).

##### Detached HEAD

`HEAD` can be in either of two states, ***attached*** or ***detached***, depending on if you've checked out a branch or not. Default state is *attached*, where any manipulation to the history is automatically recorded to the branch `HEAD` is currently referencing.

In *detached* state experimental changes can be made without impacting any existing branch. See infographic below illustrating the difference between *committing* in attached vs detached state.

[image: Illustration of HEAD in attached and detached state.]

A common misconception is that the message *You are in 'detached HEAD' state* is of erroneous tone, when in fact it just describes how `HEAD` is referencing the current snapshot.

***Operations than can leave HEAD in detached state:***

- Checking out a particular commit, i.e.

  ```
  $ git checkout 14ko3
  ```
- Explicitly checking out a remote branch, i.e.

  ```
  $ git checkout origin/master
  ```
- Switching to a branch using the detached flag, i.e.

  ```
  $ git switch master --detached
  ```
- Checking out a tag, i.e.

  ```
  $ git checkout v1.0.1
  ```
- Performing an interactive rebase, or a regular rebase containing conflicting changes

***Moving from detached to attached state***

To move from detached to attached state, you can either create a new branch from where you're at, or switch back to an existing branch.

**Note:** any commits created in detached state will eventually (post garbage collection) be discarded if you switch to another existing branch, without first persisting your changes in a new branch.

##### Inspecting the state of HEAD

Figuring out which state `HEAD` is currently in can be done in different ways, here are two options.

- Using `show`

  ```
  $ git show HEAD --oneline
  14ko3 (HEAD, master) C1

  # If attached, the output would have been
  14ko3 (HEAD -> master) C1
  ```
- Using `status`

  ```
  $ git status
  HEAD detached at 14ko3
  ```

#### *What is HEAD exactly? (technically)*

If you ever want to explicitly see what `HEAD` is referencing you can always inspect the `.git/HEAD` file, which is the actual file Git uses internally to manage `HEAD`. The file contains the name of the branch or commit hash depending on if `HEAD` is detached or not.

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master

# If detached, the output would have been
14ko36e295f1a98ec57397b3acc7bc247da61ff5
```

***Source:*** Above excerpt is taken from this full length post on the subject: [What is HEAD in Git?](https://blog.git-init.com/what-is-head-in-git/)

Comment: Hi Alexis, your blogs on git is one of the most inspirational contents I ever read about git, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for your nice comment, it's feedback like this that keeps motivating me to write more! I'm happy you found it useful.

Answer (score 19):

After reading all of the previous answers, I still wanted more clarity. This blog at the official git website http://git-scm.com/blog gave me what I was looking for:

### The HEAD: Pointer to last commit snapshot, next parent

> The HEAD in Git is the **pointer** to the current branch reference, which is in turn a **pointer** to the last commit you made or the last commit that was checked out into your working directory. That also means it will be the parent of the next commit you do. It's generally simplest to think of it as HEAD is the snapshot of your last commit.

Comment: *The HEAD: last commit snapshot, next parent* is not accurate. `HEAD` is not a commit; it *points to* one.

Comment: No need for sarcasm; before your edit, even though the quote was accurate, the big bold letters were a simplification and a bit misleading. Now, it's better.

Comment: IF you read the next line: The HEAD in Git is the **pointer** to the current branch reference, which is in turn a **pointer** to the last commit you made or the last commit that was checked out into your working directory. -- Please note the use of the word "pointer" there.

Comment: While the "last commit snapshot" description does give a conceptual feel for how HEAD is typically supposed to be used, it's really not accurate. If I make a commit, then switch to another branch, HEAD doesn't point to the last commit snapshot anymore. It points to the last commit snapshot on the branch I just switched to. If I `checkout HEAD^`, now HEAD doesn't even point to the last commit snapshot on any branch.

Comment: "The parent of your next commit (if you were to commit right now)" is more accurate, but there are many other operations in git besides commit that are affected by HEAD. Really, in the end, HEAD is HEAD, and its nature is defined by how it affects commands like `commit`, `merge`, `rebase`, `log`, etc. But conceptually maybe "(pointer to) the current position" is a good summary.

Answer (score 15):

I'd just like to detail a few things in Greg Hewgil's accepted answer.
According to the [Git Pocket Guide](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000561/index.html)

**Branch:**

> the branch itself is defined as all points reachable in the commit
>   graph from the named commit (the “tip” of the branch).

**HEAD:** A special type of Ref

> The special ref HEAD determines what branch you are on...

**Refs**

> Git defines two kinds of references, or named pointers, which it calls
>   “refs”:
>
> - A simple ref, which points directly to an object ID (usually a commit or tag)
> - A symbolic ref (or symref), which points to another ref (either simple or symbolic)

As Greg mentioned, HEAD can be in a "detached state". So HEAD can be either a simple ref (for a detached HEAD) or a symref.

> if HEAD is a symbolic ref for an existing branch, then you are “on”
>   that branch. If, on the other hand, HEAD is a simple ref directly
>   naming a commit by its SHA-1 ID, then you are not “on” any branch, but
>   rather in “detached HEAD” mode, which happens when you check out some
>   earlier commit to examine.

Comment: Thank you, @mike! This is the first answer that clarifies what happens when you check out an earlier commit. Looking at the [book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) on the git website, I got the impression that a "detached HEAD" was a pathological state you only got into if you did some weird rebasing thing.

But checking out an earlier commit is not a strange thing to do, and when you do that, HEAD is not "the tip of the current branch." So this is the first time I feel like I actually understand.

Answer (score 7):

I think 'HEAD' is current check out commit. In other words 'HEAD' points to the commit that is currently checked out.

If you have just cloned and not checked out I don't know what it points to, probably some invalid location.

Comment: Yes, the special reference `HEAD` is whatever commit you've currently got checked-out. See [the manual](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is) for details (relevant paragraph immediately follows Fig 3.4).

Comment: If you clone a repository, git will by default check out the `master` branch - so HEAD will point to master.

Comment: @sleske if you clone a repository with no special options git will check out the remote head. it is usually `master`, but it is not always. See `remote set-head`

Comment: My previous comment was correct except for the reference to `remote set-head`, which only impacts the local default branch, and won't change the default at the server.

Answer (score 6):

A great way to drive home the point made in the correct answers is to run
`git reflog HEAD`, you get a history of all of the places HEAD has pointed.

Answer (score 5):

Head points to the tip of the currently checked out branch.

[image]

In your repository, there is a .git folder. Open the file in this location: .git\refs\heads. The (sha-1 hash) code in that file (master in most cases) will be the most recent commit, i.e the one seen in the output of the command `git log`. More info on the .git folder: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html

Comment: It's a common misconception that the tip of the current branch points to the most recent commit. Typically that's true, but it's also not uncommon to `git reset HEAD^`, and then the most recent commit (the former tip) is no longer pointed to by the tip of the branch.

Answer (score 4):

It feels like that `HEAD` is just a tag for the last commit that you checked out.

This can be the tip of a specific branch (such as "master") or some in-between commit of a branch ("detached head")

Answer (score 3):

HEAD is nearly literally the head of the branch. So when you are observing a branch, you are looking at the latest commit, which is this same head of the branch. However, you can point yourself to be looking at another commit further back in the history of this branch, and when you do that, you are moving the HEAD to a previous commit. As the HEAD belonged naturally to the latest commit in the branch, it is considered detached.

A visual representation. Each branch is a caterpillar, and each commit is a segment of the creature. So the HEAD will be in the segment that is most ahead. If you remove the HEAD from that to another segment to be used, you have detached the head from the natural segment. Hope it makes any sense.

Now if you detach the HEAD in the main branch, then checkout newFeature, and checkout main again, the HEAD will still be detached, and on top of another commit. I see the HEAD as a looking glass that you can point at where you want.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all definitions, the thing that stuck in my mind was, when you make a commit, GIT creates a commit object within the repository. Commit objects should have a parent ( or multiple parents if it is a merge commit). Now, how does git know the parent of the current commit? So HEAD is a pointer to the (reference of the) last commit which will become the parent of the current commit.

Answer (score 2):

`Git` is all about commits. 
And `Head` points to the commit which you currently checked out.

```
$ git cat-file -t HEAD
commit
```

Whenever you checkout a branch, the HEAD points to the latest commit on that branch. Contents of HEAD can checked as below (for master branch):

```
$ cat .git/refs/heads/master
  b089141cc8a7d89d606b2f7c15bfdc48640a8e25
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be multiple heads in a repository. And total number of heads is always equals to total number of branches present in the repository,which means heads are nothing but latest commits of each branch

But there will be only one HEAD for a repository.HEAD is a reference which references the latest commit done at the current branch.

Its like eye of git user.Whichever commit the HEAD is referencing to, the repository starts reflecting the condition the repository had during that particular commit.

The basic nature of HEAD is to always refer the latest commit of current branch but we can move HEAD to any commit of the current branch by using git checkout "commit-hash"

Note: We can easily get commit-hash by using command **git log --oneline**

Answer (score 2):

To understand what HEAD is, let use a practical example with two different branches, `main` and `feature1` from two different developers Dev1 and Dev2 working on the same project.

Case 1 with Dev1's `main` branch:

```
name~/repo (main)
$ ls -al
total 9
drwxr-xr-x 1 AlphaLy 197121  0 Dec 22 15:09 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 AlphaLy 197121  0 Dec 21 20:35 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 AlphaLy 197121  0 Dec 22 15:09 .git/
-rw-r--r-- 1 AlphaLy 197121 20 Dec 21 20:35 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 AlphaLy 197121  0 Dec 22 15:09 test.txt
```

Next1

```
name~/repo (main) 
$ cd .git/
name~/repo/.git (GIT_DIR!)
$ ls
COMMIT_EDITMSG  description  HEAD    index  logs/     ORIG_HEAD    refs/
config          FETCH_HEAD   hooks/  info/  objects/  packed-refs
```

Next2

```
name~/repo/.git (GIT_DIR!)
$ cat HEAD
ref: refs/heads/main
```

We can clearly see that HEAD is a file with a line pointing to a file called `main` located inside the `refs/heads` directory (`heads` is a directory inside the `refs` directory). Refer to Next1 step to locate the `refs` directory

Now lets go to the Next1 step and `cd` into the `refs` directory and search for the `main` file inside the `heads` directory and see what it contains

```
name~/repo/.git (GIT_DIR!)
    $ cd refs
    
name~/repo/.git/refs (GIT_DIR!)
    $ ls
    heads/  remotes/  tags/
    
name~/repo/.git/refs/ (GIT_DIR!)
    $ cd heads/
    
name~/repo/.git/refs/heads (GIT_DIR!)
    $ ls
    main  maxi

name~/repo/.git/refs/heads (GIT_DIR!)
$ cat main
8b25d89f3396177416c055ab07ebf778616eecdd
```

`8b25d89f3396177416c055ab07ebf778616eecdd` is the current commit. So, we can say that HEAD refers to a file named `main` (always named after the current branch) that contains the current commit (the 40 digit character above). So HEAD refers to the current commit.

Case 2  with Dev2's `feature1` branch

Here, the only difference will be in the Next2 step

```
name~/repo/.git (GIT_DIR!)
$ cat HEAD
ref: refs/heads/feature1
```

and the following:

```
    name~/repo/.git (GIT_DIR!)
   $ cat feature1
03fbf973ac1014085864234010b82393208ebbd6
```

`03fbf973ac1014085864234010b82393208ebbd6` is the current commit on the `feature1` branch. So, here again HEAD refers to a file called feature1 (named after the current branch) that contains the current commit (the 40 digit character above).

Conclusion:

HEAD is refers to the current commit not the current branch. It's just a coincidence that the file that contains that current commit is named after the current branch that we tend to say that 'HEAD refers to the current branch'.

Answer (score 1):

I am also still figuring out the internals of git, and have figured out this so far:

Let's say the current branch is **master**.

1. **HEAD** is a file in your .git/ directory that normally looks something like this:

```
% cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

2. **refs/heads/master** is itself a file that normally has the hash value of the latest commit of master:

```
% cat .git/refs/heads/master 
f342e66eb1158247a98d74152a1b91543ece31b4
```

3. If you do a **git log**, you will see that this is the latest commit for master:

```
% git log --oneline 
f342e66 (HEAD -> master,...) latest commit
fa99692 parent of latest commit
```

So my thinking is the HEAD file is a convenient way to track the latest commit, instead of remembering long hash values.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is

> Figure 3-5. HEAD file pointing to the branch you’re on.

Comment: Link only answers are generally frowned upon on Stackoverflow, please inline the relevant information in your answer.

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. What `HEAD` refers to depends on whether you're talking about a bare vs a non-bare repo. In the context of a non-bare repo, it effectively refers to the currently checked-out commit, which doesn't require there to be a branch attached to it (i.e. when in detached `HEAD` state).

Answer (score 0):

These two may confusing you:

head

Pointing to named references a branch recently submitted. Unless you use the package reference , heads typically stored in $ GIT_DIR/refs/heads/.

HEAD

Current branch, or your working tree is usually generated from the tree HEAD is pointing to. HEAD must point to a head, except you are using a detached HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

A **branch** is actually a pointer that holds a commit ID such as **17a5**.
**HEAD** is a pointer to a branch the user is currently working on.

**HEAD** has a reference filw which looks like this:

ref:

You can check these files by accessing  `.git/HEAD` `.git/refs` that are in the repository you are working in.

Answer (score 0):

**HEAD actually is just a file for storing current branch info**

and if you use HEAD in your git commands you are pointing to your current branch

you can see the data of this file by
`cat .git/HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured it out myself yet, but [Silfheed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4381549/19741737)'s [link](https://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/#:%7E:text=the%20commit%20message.-,refs%3A%20References%2C%20or%20heads%20or%20branches%2C%20are%20like%20post%2Dit%20notes%20slapped%20on%20a%20node%20in%20the%20DAG.,-Where%20as%20the) to the "*post-it notes slapped on a node*" definition is the best I've found so far.

I would like to share my impressions of the search for a definition, otherwise why should I keep it to myself.
I understand it really as *stickers glued to the current position in the space of the Git tree*. I miss just such a term - **the current position in the GIT tree**, which has its own **attributes** that indicate where we are.

Such concepts as "*reference*" or "*pointer*" are not clear to me. It seems to me that they imply a new level of abstraction, from the inside of which we "refer" to something. This may not be true, but this is how I see it so far.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33463092)

Answer (score -5):

As a concept, the head is the latest revision in a branch. If you have more than one head per named branch you probably created it when doing local commits without merging, effectively creating an unnamed branch.

To have a "clean" repository, you should have one head per named branch and always merge to a named branch after you worked locally.

This is also true for [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/).

Comment: This is true for Mercurial, but _not_ for Git.