# Difference between git HEAD and the current project state?

Tags: git

I quote a git tutorial:

```
git diff shows the diff between HEAD and the current project state
```

I wonder what that means. Isn't the HEAD the current active project?

Thanks

Answer (score 134, accepted):

From "[Specifying revisions](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions)"

> `HEAD` names the commit on which you based the changes in the working tree.

There are other heads (`FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD`). See [Jefromi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529971/what-is-the-head-in-git/2530000#2530000) for more.

The thing is, by default `git diff` actually shows the differences between "the current state of your project" (i.e. your files on your working tree) and **the index** (not HEAD).
In other words, the differences are what you *could* tell git to further add to the index but you still haven't.

if you do **`git diff --cached`**, *then* it will compare the index with HEAD.

See [git book for more (archive link)](https://schacon.github.io/gitbook/3_comparing_commits_-_git_diff.html):

> A common use is to simply run
>
> ```
> $ git diff
> ```
>
> which will show you changes in the working directory that are not yet staged for the next commit. If you want to see what is staged for the next commit, you can run
>
> ```
> $ git diff --cached
> ```
>
> which will show you the difference between the index and your last commit; what you would be committing if you run "git commit" without the "-a" option. (In Git versions 1.6.1 and later, you can also use `git diff --staged` which may be easier to remember.) Lastly, you can run
>
> ```
> $ git diff HEAD
> ```
>
> which shows changes in the working directory since your last commit; what you would be committing if you run "git commit -a".

See also [365git: Getting a diff between the working tree and other commits](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/3464927214/getting-a-diff-between-the-working-tree-and-other):

[image: http://images.abizern.org.s3.amazonaws.com/365git/Feb11/Git%20Diff%202.png]

Comment: awesome link, in the 3 years of using git I haven't seen a single image that explained stuff so well. The offical git images are horrible compared to the simplicity provided by the linked image. All other images on the blog seem to be comparably awesome. I mean the official git images are rather image series which still leave room for interpretation, while the image in your post explains 5 different commands in only 1 image. This is quite the inversion of efficiency, 5 images per command compared 5 commands per image.

Comment: I don't understand this at all. Let's say I have commits like this `1-> 2 -> 3 -> 4` and I just checked out a branch off of `4`. A) Are both my head and index pointing to `4`? B) And now if checkout out back to `2` is my `Head` at this moment `2` yet my index is `4`? C) I'm asking this because I'm doing both `git diff` and `git status` on a branch and the `git diff` doesn't include all the files that were changed while the `git status` does so I thought it might have something related to this...

Comment: @Honey A/ yes. (read https://stackoverflow.com/a/45181361/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438168/git-checkout-ours-does-not-remove-files-from-unmerged-files-list to really know more about the index). B/ No, normally index and HEAD should be the same. The working tree might not though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37204243/6309. `git checkout 2 -- .` would make the working tree identical to commit 2.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff` is for showing the uncommitted changes (ie, the work that you have done but have not yet committed to the current project).

Here's a full explanation:
http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Comment: Not exactly.  VonC's answer is more accurate; `git diff` does *not* show changes that you've made, not yet committed to the project, but *have* added with a `git add`.