# GIT: git checkout --ours still showing "both modified"

Tags: linux, git, github

I'm trying to resolve merge conflict in some files

```
both modified:   myFile.h
```

I ran this command:

```
git checkout --ours myFile.h
```

after that I ran:

```
git status
```

It shows this:

```
both modified:   myFile.h
```

Why still shows "both modified" ?

Answer (score 7):

Some `git checkout` commands resolve a merge conflict, taking the version you checked out, and some don't.  This is one of the cases that don't.

You must therefore mark the conflict as resolved manually, with: `git add myFile.h`.

#### Why this is the way it is

Merging (the action, i.e., merge-as-a-verb) is done through Git's *index* (also called the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*).  The index has one entry for each file that will go into the *next commit you make*.  Normally, that one entry holds one file—but the index has four *slots* per entry, which are numbered.  Slot zero (`0`) is the normal "no conflict, file is ready to commit" slot.  Slots 1, 2, and 3 are used only during a merge conflict, and contain the *merge base* version (slot 1), `--ours` version (slot 2), and `--theirs` version (slot 3).

If slot zero is filled, the other three slots are empty.  If any of the other slots are filled, slot 0 is empty and the file is in "conflicted" state.  (It's possible to have just two of the other three slots filled, as is the case for add/add, modify/delete, and rename/delete conflicts.)

When you run `git checkout commit -- path`,<sup>1</sup> Git copies a file from the given *commit* into slot zero, then from slot zero to the work-tree.  Copying to slot zero wipes out slots 1-3 if they're filled, so the file is now resolved!

But, when you run `git checkout --ours -- path`, Git doesn't have to write anything to index slot zero, it can just get the file's contents from slot 2.  So it copies from slot 2 to the work-tree, and the file is *not* resolved.

Note that this means you can do `git checkout HEAD -- path` to extract the file from the `HEAD` commit, writing to slot zero and thus resolving as well as writing to the work-tree.  This is subtly different in another way, though.  Suppose that during the merge, Git decided that the file was *renamed* as well as being modified.  It's taken the rename into account: the file's *new* name is `evil/zorg` instead of the old name `evil-zorg`.  If you `git checkout --ours`, Git will extract the old (HEAD) version of `evil-zorg` under the new name `evil/zorg`.  If you `git checkout HEAD`, Git won't find the file under the new name!

(This is another case of Git letting implementation details show through—or, equivalently, of cramming too much stuff into one command.)

---

<sup>1</sup>The reason for the `--` is to handle a file whose name looks like an option.  (For instance, what if the file's name is `--theirs`?)  If the *path* part doesn't look like an option, you don't need the `--`.  It's a good habit to pick up, though: use the `--` every time and you won't be surprised someday when your file name *does* resemble an option.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very helpful answer. @user2924482 I believe you should mark it as an answer

Comment: To fellow `git checkout --ours/--theirs` travelers: @torek also wrote another answer to a similar question with even more gory git details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39439137/68086