# ORIG_HEAD, FETCH_HEAD, MERGE_HEAD etc

Tags: git

There's a lot of useful git references (what is the exact name for this?), e.g. `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD`, @{upstream} etc.

Is there any reference for this? A complete list with explanations?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/964876/6309

Comment: Did you have trouble searching for the answer online? It's readily available in the [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html) and [official Linux Kernel Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Answer (score 44):

`git help revisions` brings up http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions, which describes <del>all the</del> the most common ways to reference commits:

- `HEAD` names the commit on which you based the changes in the working tree.
- `FETCH_HEAD` records the branch which you fetched from a remote repository with your last git fetch invocation.
- `ORIG_HEAD` is created by commands that move your `HEAD` in a drastic way, to record the position of the `HEAD` before their operation, so that you can easily change the tip of the branch back to the state before you ran them.
- `MERGE_HEAD` records the commit(s) which you are merging into your branch when you run git merge.
- `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` records the commit which you are cherry-picking when you run git cherry-pick.

From the git source, you can also find out about `BISECT_HEAD`, `REVERT_HEAD`, `REJECT_NON_FF_HEAD` and several others that you will almost certainly never need.

That reference also explains suffixes (`^N`, `~N`, `@{...}`), ranges (`..` vs `...`), and more.

Comment: Even though `BISECT_HEAD` at al are defined in the sources, you shouldn't assume those to be around. I would expect everything listed in `git help revisions` to be supported in long run.

Answer (score 24):

`HEAD`: The current ref that you’re looking at. In most cases it’s probably `refs/heads/master`

`FETCH_HEAD`: The SHAs of branch/remote heads that were updated during the last `git fetch`

`ORIG_HEAD`: When doing a merge, this is the SHA of the branch you’re merging into.

`MERGE_HEAD`: When doing a merge, this is the SHA of the branch you’re merging from.

`CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`: When doing a cherry-pick, this is the SHA of the commit which you are cherry-picking.

The complete list of these refs can be found by cloning git sources:

`git clone https://github.com/git/git.git`

and grepping the `_HEAD"` string in `.c` files. They are dispersed all over the place, but still can be easily found.

**P.S.**

`git help revisions` does not show the list of all possible named refs.

Answer (score 7):

This is what the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation for Git revisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions) says:

> `HEAD` names the commit on which you based the changes in the working tree.
>
> `FETCH_HEAD` records the branch which you fetched from a remote repository with your last git fetch invocation.
>
> `ORIG_HEAD` is created by commands that move your `HEAD` in a drastic way, to record the position of the `HEAD` before their operation, so that you can easily change the tip of the branch back to the state before you ran them.
>
> `MERGE_HEAD` records the commit(s) which you are merging into your branch when you run git merge.
>
> `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` records the commit which you are cherry-picking when you run git cherry-pick.

Also, for `@{upstream}`:

> `<refname>@{upstream}`, e.g. `master@{upstream}`, `@{u}`
>
> > The suffix `@{upstream}` to a ref (short form `<refname>@{u}`) refers to the branch the ref is set to build on top of. A missing ref defaults to the current branch.

Answer (score 2):

These references are called pointers. They are just regular pointers in programmer terms to tree-ish entities that exist within Git. Note that a tree-ish is anything that consists of at least one commit, i.e. a branch, tag, stash or something like `HEAD`. Regarding a complete list, I think the only one that exists is the manual:

http://git-scm.com/documentation

While there is no complete list of the available special pointers like `HEAD` The manual does cover the complete list of available pointers therein, although they are kind of hard to find.

Comment: Try `git help revisions` for the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD` in Git, note that Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), [batch 11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c5b454771e6b086f60c7f1f139025f174bcedac9) defines "special ref" as a very narrow set that consists of `FETCH_HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD,` and clarifies everything else that used to be classified as such are actually just pseudorefs.

See [commit 8df4c5d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8df4c5d205263c98378f0eea2b4ebab5e5c174aa), [commit 2cd33f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2cd33f44282853d77bea9c29d1a4f88d8c3b3e5a), [commit 3f921c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f921c75913a4ba7b73cb0d8ec05a2cf24d1f4d4), [commit 35122da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35122daebc8030ccc42f54fe4f08272091e4aa94), [commit fd7c6ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd7c6ffa9e118cdf18a3752ec456070ed0a22e3b), [commit bb02e95](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bb02e95f3b25d933272bcf9d6883828d26271f69), [commit 821f663](https://github.com/git/git/commit/821f6632b091dc59562f74a0c74005b34319a2e7) (19 Jan 2024) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8282f95](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8282f9592838acd265491737e4d36636fc64b639), 29 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`Documentation`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8df4c5d205263c98378f0eea2b4ebab5e5c174aa): add "special refs" to the glossary
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> Add the "special refs" term to our glossary.

`glossary-content` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8df4c5d205263c98378f0eea2b4ebab5e5c174aa/Documentation/glossary-content.txt#L641-L654):

> ### `special ref`
>
> A ref that has different semantics than normal refs. These refs can be
> accessed via normal Git commands but may not behave the same as a
> normal ref in some cases.
>
> The following special refs are known to Git:
>
> - "`FETCH_HEAD`" is written by [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) or [`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull). It
>   may refer to multiple object IDs. Each object ID is annotated with metadata
>   indicating where it was fetched from and its fetch status.
> - "`MERGE_HEAD`" is written by [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) when resolving merge
>   conflicts. It contains all commit IDs which are being merged.

So `HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD` are pseudorefs, while `FETCH_HEAD` and `MERGE_HEAD` are "special refs".