# Remove ORIG_HEAD and FETCH_HEAD from history view in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I recently started using Eclipse Kepler with EGit plugin and these branches are not what I am used to. Is there a way to permanently stop these branches from being created? I tried removing them manually, but it does not work and I don't want to have them the next time I do fetch or rebase.

Comment: These are not really branches, in the usual sense.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595524/orig-head-fetch-head-merge-head-etc?rq=1

Comment: Do you mean Egit creates local branches for *all* remote branches it finds on cloning a repo? What a `git branch -avvv` returns in your repo (in a shell)

Comment: @torek I understand that, they are like HEAD pointer. However, I don't find them useful and would like for them not to be shown.

Comment: `git fetch` and `git rebase` will re-create them every time.  You can either manually remove the files from the `.git` subdir, or filter away the appearance of the branch names, but they will come back like a bad case of tinea cruris. :-)

Comment: @VonC These branches are not listed on git branch -avvv

Comment: @torek And how would I filter away their appearance?

Comment: Got me, I don't use Egit.  (If I did maybe I could supply a real answer...)  I note that regular git doesn't show them: I have a `.git` with `FETCH_HEAD`, `HEAD`, etc in it and `git branch` does not show those.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I understand from the comments on your question, you only want these refs not to be shown in `History` view.
You may try to uncheck `Additional Refs` from `Preferences > Team > Git > History`. This should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

ORIG_HEAD and FETCH_HEAD are symbolic refs. They simply record the sha1 of the last Origin and the last Fetch.

In one sense they are an implementation detail, but because of the scriptability of Git on Linux they can be used to provide extra power user capability.

As you delve further into the manual and tutorials you will appreciate what they can do for you (usually when you made some mistake and these refs remember an important state that you can go back to)