# Merge status lost when stashing

Tags: git, merge

It happens that information about a merge are lost after we do a stash. A usual merge and a stashed merge are compared below.

#### Right: merge + push

```
git merge release-2013-10-29
# Everything works, cool
git commit -am "Upgraded to release 2013-10-29"
git push origin dev
```

Result is as expected, a merge commit:

[image]

#### Wrong: merge + stash + push

Here I am in a scenario where I need to stash the merge changes just in order to have a look at the previous-to-the-merge behaviour.

```
git merge release-2013-11-06
# Conflicts fixed, but detected inappropriate behaviour
git stash
git stash pop
git commit -am "Upgraded to release 2013-11-06"
git push origin dev
```

Result: this commit is not a "merge" anymore. We also lost all single authored commits contained by the merge, just like if *I would* have made all these changes.

[image]

---

So, shouldn't we stash anything when merging? How to avoid such behaviour then?

Comment: Just don't use `stash`. There is nothing `stash push/pop` does that `git commit -a -m stash-commit` and `git checkout branch-with-stash-commit && git reset HEAD^` already does flawlessly (without any akward behaviour like you describe `stash` have). I really see no reason to use `git stash` any longer, I consider it to be a reliek from the very early git development.

Comment: I am not sure to follow your point. Once I fixed *a lot* of conflicts from the merge, I needed to revert back to the before-the-merge state "just to check something". None between `commit`, `checkout` or `reset` would temporarily save the conflicts I took a long time to fix. Only `stash` would. Or are you trying to say that I should just have committed my files without having verified the previous behaviour and even with some "wrong" code/merges? And more particularly, than no-one should stash anything, ever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do a merge, [git stores a reference to the branch you're merging in `MERGE_HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17595524/1679863). But it seems like `git stash` doesn't save the reference.

You can try to set the `MERGE_HEAD` back to the commit which you were merging after applying the stash:

Suppose you're merging release-2013-11-06 branch onto master, and the last commit there is - `3be2c99`, then you can do:

```
git stash apply --index
git update-ref MERGE_HEAD 3be2c99
git status
# All conflicts fixed but you're still merging
# ....
```

Notice the usage of `--index` while applying the stash. That is required to get the changes back in the index, else you will get the stashed changes only in the working tree.

P.S: Ideally you should avoid stashing your uncommitted merge.

Comment: I would underline the usage of `--index` with `git stash pop`: without it, the changes would not be applied to the index, only to the work tree, and a "conflicts resolved" state implies that the "ok to be committed" state of files which had conflicts are in the index.

Comment: @kostix Yup, added a note about it :)

Comment: @StéphaneBruckert There is a minor correction in my answer, please re-look. Actually MERGE_HEAD should point to the commit in the branch you're merging, i.e., *release-2013-11-06* in your case.

Comment: Argh. Note that if you try to apply the `MERGE_HEAD` after committing with a plan to amend the commit, you'll (well, _I_ was, anyhow) be told to take a hike. `fatal: You are in the middle of a merge -- cannot amend.`