# Is there a specific pointer for referring to an upstream branch?

Tags: git

If you're on a given branch, and you're tracking a specific remote branch, is there any pointer you can use to refer to the upstream branch you're tracking?

For example, if you're currently on branch feature/ABC-123, and you're tracking origin/feature/ABC-123, is there any shortcut that you can use to refer to it, so that you could do something like

```
git diff UPSTREAM_THINGY
```

rather than typing in

```
git diff origin/feature/ABC-123
```

Related question: [compare local git branch with remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800783/compare-local-git-branch-with-remote-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: `@{upstream}`

Courtesy of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17766249/38765), the git documentation for [specifying revisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions) has:

> `<branchname>@{upstream}`, e.g. `master@{upstream}`, `@{u}`
>   The suffix
>   `@{upstream}` to a `branchname` (short form `<branchname>@{u}`) refers to
>   the branch that the branch specified by `branchname` is set to build on
>   top of (configured with `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.merge`).
>   A missing `branchname` defaults to the current one.

Comment: Incidentally `@{u}` is quite useful with `git log` as well.  From my years with Mercurial I wanted the Git equivalent of `incoming` and `outgoing`, and they are: `git config --global alias.incoming 'log --oneline ..@{u}'` and `git config --global alias.outgoing 'log --oneline @{u}..'`.  Since then I decided I usually want to `git log -p` incoming (no `--oneline`, with or without `-p`), so I made a shorter `lin` alias which expands to just `log ..@{u}` used as `git lin` or `git lin -p` (I don't need this for `outgoing`, I still use `git outgoing` for that).

Comment: @torek sometimes I wish answers were allowable for comments. :(