# What is the name of pointers like `HEAD~1` in git?

Tags: git

I'm aware that `HEAD~1` represents the parent of the commit `HEAD` is on and that `HEAD^2` represents the second parent of the commit `HEAD` is on.

From `git reflog`, `HEAD@{n}` is a [gitrevision](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).

Do pointers like `HEAD~n`, `HEAD^n`, `HEAD~3^2`, `master~1`, `cb2510e~1` etc. have a special name? Are they references in the same way that branches point to a specific commit? Is it called a relative reference?

I've been trying to look, but have not been successful. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: I don't think `HEAD` can be a permanent ref because it is different for every branch.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529971/what-is-the-head-in-git

Comment: HEAD in more or less words just represents where you currently are in git

Comment: really I just want to know if there is a "git" semantic name for pointers like `HEAD~1`

Comment: The link I pasted above uses the language `pointer`, `ref`, and `symbolic ref`.

Comment: Ah, they are just things that are known colloquially then? thought they might have a specific name in the git vernacular, similar to a `gitrevision`

Comment: Maybe it does.  Git has a rather loose technical language.  It is more important to just know what `HEAD` and `master~1` mean rather than what to call them.

Comment: ^ completely agree, just putting together a lesson plan and wanted to have a definitive name, but thanks for the talk through! if anyone does know plz post answer!

Comment: Note: `HEAD^2` is the second parent; `HEAD~2` is the first parent of the first parent (equivalent to `HEAD^1^1`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that *all* of these are, collectively, "git revisions" (or `gitrevisions` as one word).  Note that all of these are listed in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

Unfortunately, this term also seems to encompass range notations such as `origin/master..master`.  For discussion purposes we would *like* to have a term that is specific to the two halves of such an expression, so as to construct a formal grammar.  Git does not define one, so you must invent your own.  The closest seems to be the phrase *extended SHA-1 syntax*, as [jsageryd noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49683837/1256452).  This is a particularly poor term: despite its clumsiness, it's too specific, given that there is a long term effort to move Git from SHA-1 to some other hashing algorithm.

Internally, within the source to Git, there is a move to rename these to `OID`, which stands for **O**bject **ID**entifier.  OID seems like the most appropriate term.  However, internally, this is for the fully resolved thing that is currently a 160-bit SHA-1 and will eventually be larger.  Perhaps *extended OID*? :-)

Answer (score 0):

A term used both in [man gitrevisions](https://gitirc.eu/gitrevisions.html) and in commit messages in the Git project is "extended SHA-1 syntax".

Although, I am inclined to think that its usage is for the most part limited to technical discussions about Git internals. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A name I saw used for them which stuck with me is "revspec" which does pair nicely with "refspec", the pairing used to describe how fetch and push should map refnames in the different repositories.  I don't recall where I saw it and I don't recall ever using it, a git grep on the source says it only occurs in the sample post-receive hook, googling says others do use it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find out about that *extended SHA-1* syntax --- but that seems to be a git thing. Maybe this is even meant with a grain of humour: the "canonical" name would be the (abrrev.) SHA-1 name. But for practical reasons you have HEAD (and @) and this extended (a bit cryptic) syntax.

"SPECIFYING REVISIONS" is the big title in `gitrevisions`.

> A **revision parameter `<rev>`** typically, but not necessarily, names a
>   **commit object**. It uses what is called an *extended SHA-1 syntax*. Here
>   are various ways to spell **object names**. The ones listed near the end
>   of this list name trees and blobs contained in a commit.

So `HEAD~1` would be a name for (= a way to spell) a commit object, whose (real) name is "7ah25e...".