# "HEAD" equivalent in detached HEAD state

Tags: git, push, git-detached-head

Lets say I'm in a detached HEAD state and I run the following command:

`git push origin HEAD:foo`

git will output the following error:

```
error: The destination you provided is not a full refname (i.e.,
starting with "refs/"). We tried to guess what you meant by:

- Looking for a ref that matches 'foo' on the remote side.
- Checking if the <src> being pushed ('HEAD')
  is a ref in "refs/{heads,tags}/". If so we add a corresponding
  refs/{heads,tags}/ prefix on the remote side.

Neither worked, so we gave up. You must fully qualify the ref.
hint: The <src> part of the refspec is a commit object.
hint: Did you mean to create a new branch by pushing to
hint: 'HEAD:refs/heads/foo'?
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://server/DefaultCollection/Project/_git/Repo'
```

So my question is: What is the correct keyword to use here instead of "HEAD" to reference the current commit I'm on? I can copy paste the commit id, but that's obviously silly. I'm asking for a constant name I can type, like head, to represent the current commit I'm on.

Comment: Why is copying the current commit id silly? If you really want a name toreference the current commit other than "HEAD" you can create a git tag to refer to the commit

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. If your tools treat text as some sort of mysterious creature they can't deal with except as undifferentiated pixels, use better tools Screenshots are a _horrible_ way of talking about code-related matters. `xterm` will do an html or svg screen dump that preserves colors and such in case that matters, surely every can do as well.

Comment: You should spell `HEAD` in all uppercase. Lowercase will *sometimes* work, and sometimes not. To see why, read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72646647/1256452) to [HEAD vs head vs detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72643098/1256452). (This isn't the issue here, it's just a general rule. The actual issue is the one in [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72648913/1256452).) Note: if you don't like holding down the shift key that long, consider using `@` instead of `HEAD`: it works the same and avoids typing three of the four characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [jthill notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72648913/1256452), when `HEAD` is detached, Git doesn't know whether:

```
git push origin HEAD:foo
```

is meant to create `refs/heads/foo` (a branch named `foo`) on `origin`, or `refs/tags/foo` (a tag named `foo`) on `origin`, or perhaps some other kind of ref (e.g., Gerrit's magic `refs/for/foo`<sup>1</sup>).

Because you are in detached-HEAD mode in your current working tree, you must assist Git here.  You can:

```
git push origin @:refs/heads/foo
```

to tell Git: *Use `HEAD`, in all upper case,<sup>2</sup> to find the commit in my repository.  Push that commit and any necessary parents to `origin`, then ask `origin` to create a **branch** named `foo`.*

It's probably easier, though, to just go ahead and create a local branch named `foo`:

```
git switch -c foo
```

after which `git push -u origin @` suffices.  You might even wish to make an alias (shell alias or Git alias) or shell function out of this:

```
push-new-as foo
```

where `push-new-as` expands to `git switch -c $1 && git push -u origin @` for instance.  (Add additional protections, such as making sure there's no `origin/foo` first, if you like: that's probably actually a good idea.  Have the alias-or-shell-function run `git fetch origin` first.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Gerrit is written in JGit and doesn't implement Git quite the same as C Git.  Pushing to a `refs/for/` namespace name creates a Gerrit changeset, which Gerrit sneakily renames into yet another name.  Your own (probably C-Git based) Git *thinks* Gerrit created `refs/for/foo` successfully, as their JGit implemention returns a success indication at this point, but it really didn't.  This little lie facilitates useful work and causes no actual problems, but it's definitely rather magic.

<sup>2</sup>See [HEAD vs head vs detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72643098/1256452) for why the upper vs lower case distinction is important.

Comment: I actually like this answer better than mine.

Comment: `git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/foo` works well for me. I see now that it's actually directly in the error message, I just didn't understand it enough to see that. Thank you for the complete explanation! For some context, my use case for this is mainly sub-modules which pretty much always end up in a detached state regardless what you do. Don't really want the extra step of makin a local branch every time I need to push. I can use reflog to find the commit if I do something stupid and lose it rofl.

Answer (score 2):

`HEAD` is your current checkout. If you don't say the destination type explicitly (by supplying the `refs/<type>/` prefix, e.g. `refs/heads/` for branch tips), Git tries to figure out what you meant by copying the type from the source. But when you don't have a branch checked out and you supply `HEAD`, there's no type to copy. It's just some random commit you're working on. That's what ... yeah, that error message you posted a picture of ... is talking about: you didn't say what kind of ref you're trying to create.

Comment: The question is about `head`, not `HEAD`.

Comment: @matt but `head` isn't a branch or a tag in OP's repo, the error message says so, and OP mentioned "detached head state" as if they learned on a case-blind filesystem.

Comment: I'm afraid we don't know enough about what the user typed and what Git said in reply for us to know what the error message says or is responding to.

Comment: @matt: it's true we can't be 100% positive. But I'm pretty sure.