# Git pull origin HEAD

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-pull

I was taught that you could push to and pull from a remote branch matching the name of your current Git branch by doing:

```
git push origin HEAD
```

or

```
git pull origin HEAD
```

Its always worked for me before, but it strangely doesn't work sometimes, instead deferring to push/pulling from the **master** branch instead (which causes a merge on pull... not what I want to do). I know that you can easily push/pull from the branch you're on by simply using the name of the branch like:

```
git pull origin name-of-branch-i-want-to-pull-from
```

**Anyway**:

1. Is there some reason that the HEAD is losing track/not pointing to my current branch, like it almost always does?
2. Is there any way to push/pull to the branch that I'm currently working on (as long as the remote branch's name matches) without explicitly naming the branch in the command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to some serious help by @abackstrom, I was able to fix my issue.
Essentially, this post was my problem, and solution:

[Git branch named origin/HEAD -> origin/master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359099/git-branch-named-origin-head-origin-master)

The exact command to "recreate"/track a local HEAD branch/pointer correctly was:

```
git remote set-head origin -a
```

I hope this helps anyone else that runs into this issue.

Answer (score 11):

The thing is, when you do:

```
git push origin HEAD
```

`HEAD` here means the default branch on your **local** repository.

However, when you do:

```
git pull origin HEAD
```

`HEAD` here means the default branch on your **remote** repository.

These 2 HEADs can have the same branch name, but very often they are different.

For example, if the default branch of your local repository and remote repository are both `master`, then you switched to a new branch `feature` on local repository, then pushed it to remote by doing `git push origin HEAD`, the default branch on remote won't be changed to `feature` magically. Instead it will stay at `master`. At this point, if you do `git pull origin HEAD` on your feature branch, you are actually doing `git pull origin master`.

So I would suggest avoid doing `git pull origin HEAD`, because it's not obvious what's the default branch is on the remote, and can cause unexpected problems.

Answer (score 6):

HEAD is not really a branch. It's a pointer to the commit that you currently have checked out, and will often reference a branch, but if you do something like `git checkout <sha>` or `git checkout <tag>`, then HEAD references a commit directly, with no tie to a branch - this is called a "detached HEAD" state, and you should normally get a warning from `git checkout` when you enter such a state. In that state, trying to push/pull HEAD doesn't make sense, since you're not on a branch.

Comment: Yea, that absolutely makes sense, because then you're tracking a non-branch, but that's not what's happening here.

Instead, I'm currently tracking a branch (for example titled 'patch'), I commit, and then I:
`git push origin HEAD`
and it pushes to origin/master
It happens on pull too. Strange.