# HEAD doesn't point to the current branch?

Tags: git

I wonder, is not `HEAD` is the current branch? As far as I'm concerned it is. But this shows that this is not the case:

```
$ git branch
* develop
  master
```

So the current branch is develop. But HEAD is not:

```
 $ git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/develop
  origin/master
```

Comment: This is a question that gets asked a lot on Stack Overflow, but I haven't been able to find a good canonical for it yet. When I find one, I'll have to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [How does origin/HEAD get set?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8839958/456814).

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [Git branch named origin/HEAD -> origin/master](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4359099/456814).

Comment: Related: [What is the use of the origin/HEAD branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8223406/456814).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of the origin/HEAD branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223406/what-is-the-use-of-the-origin-head-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HEAD in your local repository references the currently checked-out commit, which may or may not also be the location of a branch. So HEAD in a local repository ***does not*** always refer to the currently checked-out branch. For example, you can enter a "detached HEAD" state by checking out a commit directly.

**However, in the context of remote repositories, HEAD refers to the default branch for that remote.** So

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

means that the default branch on `origin` is the master branch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8223893/2813589 - says it points to the current branch in local, whereas you said `So HEAD in a local repository does not always refer to the currently checked-out branch.`. How is that?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp simple, **that other answer is wrong**.

Comment: Then I don't understand. Does HEAD refer to a branch or commit?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp in a non-bare local repository, it refers to the current commit. In the case of your remote origin, it refers to the default branch, ***on the origin remote***. I think the default branch thing applies to bare repositories in general, but I need to double check that.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp also note that although [the documentation itself](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html) says that HEAD refers to the current branch, that isn't quite correct, the documentation is misleading `:P`.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `-r` option, so it lists the remote-tracking branches.

```
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
```

means the `HEAD` in the remote refs the `HEAD` of remote branch `origin/master`.