# Revert to local commit?

Tags: git

I've pulled code down from my repo which has messed things up. I'd like to revert my entire project to my last local commit. How would I do this?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This will reset everything to your *current* commit (getting rid of all changes, staged or otherwise:

```
git reset HEAD --hard
```

This will reset everything to the *previous* commit (also getting rid of all changes, staged or otherwise)

```
git reset HEAD^ --hard
```

the ^ next to HEAD means **one** commit before HEAD, HEAD being where you are currently. You can go two commits back by using ^^, or three with ^^^. Additionally you can use a tilde to specify the number of commits: ~3 for three commits back.

```
git reset HEAD~3 --hard
```

Also keep in mind that the --hard option means that these commands will throw away any changes you have that are not stashed.

Comment: It's always nice to see appropriate safety warnings attached to the suggestion to use `git reset --hard`, as in this answer - a worrying number of stackoverflow answers don't...

Comment: Massive caveat of "If you've done a pull since your local commit this will nuke your local commit" :) see this to undo said ball ache http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html

Comment: @EdBishop Nice thing about Git is that you nearly never actually lose anything

Comment: @ChrisRasys indeed, it's saved us a few times :D

Answer (score 18):

Locate your last local commit in `git log` and run `git reset --hard <commit sha1>`.

It will delete all the local changes you haven't commited, and will move the [HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-git-head-exactly) to this commit.

Answer (score 4):

`git pull` can fetch and merge multiple commits.  To go back to your previous local state (rather than back n-commits) you can use the *reflog*.  `git reset --hard @{1}`