# Git remote origin has two branches

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am using TortoiseGit for Windows. I see two branches on remote/origin:

```
HEAD        20 minutes ago      Some commit message.
master      20 minutes ago      Some commit message.
```

I am confused why HEAD shows up as a branch; I did not explicitly create a separate branch on origin - it should only be 'master'. It's not really a problem, since they seem to update together anyway.

If I execute `git branch` on origin, it only shows 'master'.

Why are there two branches? Is this a TortoiseGit-specific thing, or a Git-specific thing? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is HEAD in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a git-specific thing. `HEAD` is a reference to the currently checked out thing, i.e. usually a branch. In your case, `HEAD` is simply an alias for `master`. TortoiseGit apparently can't tell an alias ("symbolic ref") from a normal branch, so it appears as if `HEAD` is an extra branch when it really isn't.

The situation is a bit different for remote repositories which usually don't have anything checked out at all. You seem to be looking at a remote repository here. In that case, that repository's `HEAD` is used to determine which branch is checked out by default when someone clones that repository. That's why, when you clone, some branch or another is checked out: git doesn't just randomly pick a branch, but it looks at the source repository's `HEAD` to make that decision.

Answer (score 0):

`HEAD` is the current revision. It's best answered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-git-head-exactly) right here. It will be exactly the same as the currently checked out ref.

Answer (score 0):

HEAD is the current "head" of the remote repo and would usually be same as the master. It is the current checked out branch / ref and is from the `.git/HEAD` file in the repo which has content like:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```