# How to reset current branch and merge to already existing branch

Tags: git, branch

Honesty speaking i tried so hard to resolve my issue by googling . I even found some of the fantastic resources like ([1](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.3/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge)) ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-git-head-exactly)) but still i don't understood.

Initially,my problem was branch conflicting.I created one feature in branch called `user-creation` .And, after then i realized that there was one major bug in my master branch . So i check `checkout` and corrected it. Then i started working on my `user-creation` branch and implemented the desire feature and fixed the old bug which i already fixed in my master branch .

Due to this on merging,some conflict arose. Because git changed hundreds of file and put this `<<<<<<< HEAD` . I though it would be good if delete all my files except `.gitconfig` , `.git/` `.^g` and merge my existing `user-creation` branch with `master` one.

No matter how much i tried to

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

i didn't came to my successful result .

If someone please tell me

1. How to copy all folders of `user-creation` branch in `master` branch in best possible way and easy way.
2. Why conflict arises . I didn't worked with team . I took all precautions. do my computer hacked ? or working in multiple tab-terminal may cause problem like this .

Comment: Dear downvoter, Please tell me what's the reason you downvoted so that next time i will keep it in mind while asking question.

Answer (score 0):

You should rebase your feature branch on top of `master`: that way, you keep all the fixes from `master` while applying the work you did on `feature` again.