# Any Git shortcuts for the current branch and the branch it tracks?

Tags: git, branch, shortcut

I would like to do something like this:

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git rebase -i origin/a_very_very_very_long_branch_name
```

Where, my local branch name is as same as `a_very_very_very_long_branch_name`.

So when I execute this kind of command, I don't want to copy and paste the long branch name again and again.

Are there any shortcuts for the current branch name in Git?

Comment: If you tab out, it should autocomplete your branch name.

Comment: @jerome.s yeah, but i have, or, let's say, the project have too many branches( i know it's not good, but C'est La Vie ;(  ). so i'm still finding the "shortcuts"

Comment: you might want to try out git-completion https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

Comment: @SébastienDawans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370845/is-there-any-shortcuts-for-current-git-branch?noredirect=1#comment23459292_16370845

Comment: I think you're looking for `HEAD`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-git-head-exactly/2304106

Comment: @jerome.s since I launch the the `sh.exe --login -i` (windows), in *emacs* therefore tab out isn't an option that can be taken for granted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your particular example, if your branch is tracking the remote branch, you can just do

```
git fetch
git rebase -i
```

Without parameters.

In case your branch is not tracking the remote branch, that can be set up by doing

```
git branch -u origin/a_very_very_very_long_branch_name
```

Comment: Though it's usable in the provided _example_ it is not exactly what was asked for: "shortcut for current branch name". (I aware that the TO had a X/Y problem because she/he actually wanted to know the upstream/remote branch name. But I'll ignore that since the text is clear and the question is old.)

Answer (score 4):

If your branch is set up to track the remote branch of the same name in `origin`, you can use `@{u}` as pointed out in [the manpage `gitrevisions`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html):

> **`<branchname>@{upstream}`, e.g. `master@{upstream}`, `@{u}`**
>
> The suffix `@{upstream}` to a branchname (short form `<branchname>@{u}`) refers to the branch that the branch specified by branchname is set to build on top of. A missing branchname defaults to the current one.

Comment: Now I can do `git difftool @{u}` for diffing current and remote branch.

Answer (score 2):

You could always create an alias to do the rebase to origin/current-branch;

`git fetch ; git rebase -i origin/$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)`

Or, if you don't specifically need the interactive part of the rebase;

`git pull --rebase`