# What does "checkout head" do?

Tags: git

I tried the following out of curiosity:

```
git checkout head
```

And I got this:

```
$ git checkout head
Note: checking out 'head'.
You are in 'detached HEAD' state.

Me@MyPC /c/repo ((9da1bd7...))
$
```

Whereas

```
git checkout HEAD
```

does nothing (as expected).
So what exactly is the former command doing?

More info: Yes, I am on Windows. And it did not create a tag or a branch as far as I can tell:

```
Me@MyPC /c/repo ((9da1bd7...))
$ git log -n 1
commit 9da1bd740434923ae55ca1b50efb7c62eb6e0c35
Author: someone else
Date:   Fri Dec 6 15:44:08 2013 +0100

Me@MyPC /c/repo ((9da1bd7...))
$ git tag -l
TestRelease

Me@MyPC /c/repo ((9da1bd7...))
$ git branch -l
* (detached from head)
  master
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-git-head-exactly/4381549#4381549) to a similar question.

Comment: I advise to use `gitk`. There is no need to do everything from command line. `Gitk` is great for checkouts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At https://github.com/git/git/blob/ad7044857660af7ffaaf8fbbccc77b817d1b938f/builtin/checkout.c#L624 the string `"HEAD"` is special-cased as a no-op, with a `strcmp` (case-sensitive). Elsewhere in the git system, something parses the argument to `checkout` case-insensitively (or looks it up as a filename, making it possibly case-insensitive depending on the filesystem).

Comment: I don't think it's in git, I think it's in the file system. The OP is on Windows, which uses a case insensitive file system, and HEAD is stored as a regular file named "HEAD", so on Windows, looking for "head" will produce a match.

Comment: Ah yes, my test was on cygwin too. Anyway, the case-sensitive special case explains why `HEAD` in all caps behaves differently. Answer updated.

Comment: So it does checkout HEAD, but because the comparison to "HEAD" fails, it thinks this is another branch. Consequently the repo is set to detached HEAD state and I receive a warning?

Comment: Right... you asked for `head` so it looks for `.git/head` (among other things) and succeeds because `.git/HEAD` exists and Windows can't tell the difference. Then git thinks it has successfully opened a file that is *not* called "HEAD", and also is not a branch (because it wasn't found in `.git/refs/heads`) so it treats it the same as any other non-special non-branch checkout.

Answer (score 1):

From what you pointed out. I would think that you have a `head` tag which is pointing on the non latest commit in the branch you're currently in.

I tried doing what you did on a clean repo (tested on Ubuntu), and it complained about the non existing branch `head`.

```
$git init  
$git checkout head
head error: pathspec 'head' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: As git says "You are in 'detached HEAD' state." I think it is a tag and not a branch. This can be checked with this command `git tag -l head` : if it displays `head` there is a tag named head.

Comment: "A branch that does not point to the latest commit on that branch" makes no sense, unless I'm really misunderstanding what you're trying to say.

Comment: You are right, this was meaningless. Thanks for pointing it out.