# git diff between HEAD and last commit gives Warning: ignoring dangling symref

Tags: git, git-diff

I am getting some weird output on trying to do diff between HEAD and last commit

```
Fatal: ambiguous argument 'head^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

While using `git diff <sha> HEAD^`, I get the error

```
warning: ignoring dangling symref head. warning: ignoring dangling symref head.
fatal: ambiguous argument 'head^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

am I missing something?

Comment: try `git diff HEAD^` instead of `git diff head^`.

Comment: warning: ignoring dangling symref head.
warning: ignoring dangling symref head.
fatal: ambiguous argument 'head^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think there can be 2 possible reasons here

1) Issue here is, you are trying to do a `git diff <sha> head^`

In this case, you need to correct your command to `git diff <sha> HEAD^`. Note the upper case characters. Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2304087/1860929) to read more about `HEAD`.

2) You are trying `git diff <sha> HEAD^` and are still getting the error message. In this case, I think you have only one commit in your repository. While the `sha` points to that lone commit, your `HEAD` also happens to point at that first commit, and `HEAD^` happens to point at the commit before that, which doesn't exist, so the error.

Another possibility here is that someone upstream has created a `dangling symref` (a [dangling object](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#dangling-objects)) while doing a merge or a `git reset` or a `git rebase`. This should be removable by doing a `git prune`.