# What is the difference between git push origin HEAD and git push origin [current-branch-name]?

Tags: git, push

It looks like both accomplish the same task to me.
Are there cases in which they are different?

What is the difference between:
`git push origin HEAD`
`git push origin [current-branch-name]`

Comment: My most favorite command `git push -u origin HEAD --force`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They mean exactly the same, since HEAD points to the **tip of the current branch**. See [this answer for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2304106/2082964).

#### EDIT:

The only case in which this would not give the same result is when you are in **detached HEAD** state; but in that case, what is your definition of `[current-branch-name]`?