# Remembering original branch in git alias

Tags: git

I'd like to create a git alias that does stuff on a different branch than HEAD is on, and then switches back to the original branch. But I'm not sure if there's any way to remember the old branch. I tried using a tag:

```
git tag placeholder &&
  git co master &&
  git co placeholder &&
  git tag -d placeholder
```

But this leaves me with a detached HEAD, rather than on the original branch.

Comment: Once you delete the placeholder, there is no other reference to the commit other than detached HEAD. maybe you intended on checking out master again?

Comment: What do you want to do if you were initially on a "detached HEAD" (at a tag or whatever)?

Comment: I'm willing to assume that at the start, HEAD is at the end of a branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git checkout -` (that is, just a dash at the end) to go back to the last branch you had checked out (like how `cd -` works).

Comment: I had no idea `cd -` was a thing. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your intended work something like this:

```
[alias]
        bookmark = "!export OLD_HEAD=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`; git checkout develop; <do stuff>; git checkout $OLD_HEAD"
```

Essentially this saves the current branch to an environment variable, does the intended work, and checks out the original branch.

Comment: According to the docs, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref <object>` should return a "non-ambiguous short name of the objects name". But it seems to me that "HEAD" is similarly non-ambiguous, and short. Why, then, is the name of the branch returned?

Comment: HEAD is a reference to a real object. Essentially the command follows the link that HEAD holds and gets the real object, in this case the branch you are on.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git for more info.