# What's the difference between `git reset --hard master` and `git reset --hard origin/master`?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-reset

I tried a lot of links on Stackoverflow/elsewhere to properly understand behaviour of

`git reset --hard option`

I know that:

- If it is omitted or if it is `origin`, reset is done on most recent commit on `origin`
- If a SHA1 hash is provided, reset is done on the corresponding commit.

What I don't understand are the following values:

1. `origin`
2. `HEAD`
3. `origin/master`
4. `origin/branch`

All seem to have same behavior i.e. they a  point to latest commit on `master`.

Please explain what is the significance of all 4 value option provided above.

I would also like to know if I am on a specific branch how can I reset to the last commit on that very branch? 
If for example I am on `v1.2`, `origin/v1.2` still takes me to latest commit on `master`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all you need to understand that branch and tag names are just pointers to hash values, which represent a single commit, if you say that there's 4 options that have the same behaviour, then the first logical answer is because they all point to the same commit

- `origin` I'm not sure about this but i think `origin` by it self will resolve to `origin/HEAD` which i think will be dependent on your github settings, in github you set a 'default branch', `origin/head` will resolve to `origin/[default_branch]`, in your case im assuming it's master, so this is why it has the same effect as `origin/master`.
- `HEAD` always points to the current commit, the one you are standing on, so a `git reset --hard HEAD` will permenantly remove all changes in tracked files and staged files changes, but not change the commit hash.
- `origin/master` is last commit in the remote master branch since your last fetch/pull, each time you commit to `master`, your local `master` is updated and your `origin/master` is updated too, if someone else pushes to `master` your repo will have no idea that there is an update, unless you do a `git fetch` then your `origin/master` will move ahead of your `master`, or maybe even diverge.
  running a `git reset --hard origin/master` will have the same effect if you are currently are on the `master` branch and the `master` is in sync with `origin/master`
- `origin/branch` I'm not sure what this represents, because there's no `origin/branch` by default, so I'm guessing you created a branch called `branch` and happens to be in the same commit as your master, to confirm you can try doing a `git branch` to see all your branches, i'm guessing you'll find one called `branch`

To see all this in a visual way, you could try running `git log --graph --decorate --all` or I prefer a visual tool like `gitk`, if you have the binary installed you would run `gitk --all` to see all branches relative to each other

Comment: `origin` can be explained by the `<refname>` entry in `gitrevisions(7)`; it fully expands to `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`. `origin/master` expands to `refs/remotes/origin/master`, and similarly `origin/branch` would expand to `refs/remotes/origin/branch` (assuming, as you said, that it exists).

Answer (score 4):

`master`, `HEAD`, `origin/something` and maybe some tag, why not, *may* all point to the same commit, but they are most definitely not the same thing.

`origin` is usually the name of a [*remote* repository](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).

You can see your remotes and configure new ones with `git remote -v`.

Try it (with `-v`) and it will probably make sense.

`remote/somebranch` points to the head of some branch on a remote repository.

`origin/master` points to the head of `master` on `origin`.

Is it the same as `master`?

Yes and no. If you pull your master branch, do some work and in the meantime somebody else commits on `master` and pushes to `origin`, they will differ.

When you do a `git fetch origin`, then, `origin/master` will have additional commits (will be *ahead*).

`HEAD` is simply "the current commit". 
Think of it as `.`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git)

Again, this *could* be the same as `master`, but if you check out another branch or commit or are in the middle of a rebase, well, it's not.

So try this on a fresh repository on which nobody else is working:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git log -1 --format="%H" HEAD
123abc
$ git log -1 --format="%H" origin/master
123abc
```

They are the same!

```
$ git diff origin/master
```

Of course their content is the same.

```
$ echo "foo" > foo
$ git add foo
$ git commit -m "Foo the thingy"
$ git log -1 --format="%H" HEAD
321bca
$ git log -1 --format="%H" origin/master
123abc
```

Ah, look, now they're different commits!

```
$ git push origin master
$ git log -1 --format="%H" HEAD
321bca
$ git log -1 --format="%H" origin/master
321bca
```

And now they aren't! we have pushed our latest commit and they both point to the same.

```
$ git checkout -b newbranch
$ echo "baz" > baz
$ git add baz
$ git commit -m "Baz the thingy with the stuff"
$ git branch -a
  master
* new_branch
  origin/master
$ git log -1 --format="%H"
789def
$ git log -1 --format="%H" master
321bca
git log -1 --format="%H" origin/master
321bca
git log -1 --format="%H" origin/new_branch
unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Of course not. We haven't pushed `new_branch` to `origin`, it is only on our local machine

```
git checkout 123abc
```

We have just checked out `123abc`, the old head of `master`. It is not the head of any branch, now, but we can check it out just the same.

```
Note: checking out 123abc. You are in 'detached HEAD' state, etc
$ git checkout -b old_master
$ git branch -a
  master
* new_branch
  origin/master
  old_master
```

Now guess what their SHA1 will respectively be?