# Create branch afterwards, apply tags and use specific commit for both branches

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-branch, branching-and-merging

Currently I only have a master branch. Now I should create a new branch called MDM, which should reflect a certain version of a program.

[image: Current planned branches with commits]

To do this I would create the new branch from the commit from May 13:

```
git checkout -b MDM dba331
git tag -a MDM1.0.0 -m 'v. 1.0.0'
```

I also would tag it. Then I would do that for the second commit:

```
git checkout master
git checkout 694aef
git checkout MDM
git merge master
git tag -a MDM1.0.1 -m 'v. 1.0.1'
git checkout master
git checkout dbf2611
```

So I take an old version of the master and merge it into my MDM branch and tag it. Finally, I want to set the master to it's latest state.

I think that should work in this way. My main problem is the commit from June 15. I only want this commit in my MDM branch (this means excluding the commit from June 10). Should I use a patch for this? Or should I use `git cherry-pick`? The commit (June 15) can stay in the master branch, but the commit from June 10 should not be in the MDM branch.

In future I think I will need a new branch for every bug/feature so that merging between branches is much simpler.

Comment: What's the purpose of doing `git checkout` multiple times in a row? Are you trying to update your `MDM` branch to those particular commits on `master`, i.e. `694aef` and `dbf2611`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. In the first checkout `git checkout master` I want to switch to the master branch. With `git checkout 694aef` I want to temporarily set the master branch on a specific commit. With `it checkout MDM` I want to switch to the MDM branch and with the following `merge` command I want to merge the specific point in history of the master (*694aef*) to my MDM branch.  Perhaps one could summarize that to `git checkout master 694aef`. Thats the theory.

Comment: That's not how `checkout` works. `git checkout 694aef` doesn't modify `master` at all; it simply puts you into a detached head state at `694aef`. If you only want those specific commits, and nothing in between them, `cherry-pick` is indeed your best solution.

Comment: So when I try to merge from the master branch with the detached head state, this detached head state is not taken as base for merging?

Comment: That's my point: the `master` branch *is not* in a detached head state. It stays right where it is. When you `checkout 694aef`, [*`HEAD`*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git) (essentially "what's currently in my working copy") gets into a detached head state. But then you immediately `git checkout MDM`, moving `HEAD` back to `MDM`. If you're on `MDM`, the sequence `git checkout master`, `git checkout 694aef`, `git checkout MDM` is essentially a no-op.

Comment: Correct. In fact, once you do `git checkout mdm`, you are no longer in a detached head state anyway. If you want to merge a particular commit (say, 694aef), just do `git merge 694aef`. Note that this will include all the changes _before_ that commit as well. As Chris said, if you just want that specific commit, do `git cherry-pick 694aef`.

Answer (score 2):

Use cherrypick, it's simpler and it create and apply a patch behind the scene...