# What is the difference between "git push origin HEAD:clean_up" and without HEAD?

Tags: git, version-control

What is the difference between

```
git push origin HEAD:clean_up
```

and

```
git push origin clean_up
```

What does `HEAD` actually mean ?

Comment: This is already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git

Comment: Please review the answer given below.

Answer (score 2):

`HEAD` points to the last commit of the current branch.  So if the current branch be `clean_up`, then I would expect the following two commands to do the same thing:

```
git push origin HEAD:clean_up
git push origin clean_up
```

I can think of one scenario where you might want to use something other than `HEAD` when doing a `git push`.  Suppose you checked out a certain branch `branch` in detached `HEAD` state.  You made a few commits in it, and now you have decided that you want to push it out to repository as a new branch of its own.  However, you want to push out the branch from one commit *before* the last commit you made.  In this case, you would take the following steps:

```
git checkout <SHA-1 of `branch` you want>
# make a few commits
git push origin HEAD~1:new_branch
```

This would push out `branch` to the remote up to and including the previous commit you made.

Comment: The main difference between the two statements is that `git push origin HEAD:clean_up` will push current local branch (with an arbitrary name) to the branch `clean_up` on origin, and `git push origin clean_up` will push a local branch named `clean_up` to a branch with the same name on origin.