# Switch to a remote branch getting detached head

Tags: git, git-detached-head

Here is a list of all my branches:

```
$ git branch -a
* temp
  remotes/heroku/master
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/master
```

When I type  `git checkout remotes/origin/master` to switch to my origin `master` branch, Git switches to a detached HEAD state. Why?

Answer (score 13):

This is the right behavior since you have checked out the **remote** branch.

If you wish to check out master and work on it you should do this now:

```
# checkout remote branch as local branch
# this will look up the branch name locally and if it does not find it it
#will checkout your remote branch with this name.
git checkout master
```

When you checkout remote branch you are simply pointing your [HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716) to the latest commit from this branch. If you wish to work on it you have to check it out as local branch without the **`remote/<branch>`**. This will automatically checkout and create local branch with the given name.

If you wish to learn more about the [HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716) read all about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716).

---

#### What is a detached HEAD?

A detached HEAD mean that your HEAD point to a commit which is not the latest in the commit chain.

In this sample commit #4 is the latest while the HEAD is pointing to commit #2.

[image]

Comment: hi @codeWizard, thank you for your reply, in fact , i have three branchs , one for heroku and 2 (dev/master) for my repos server, i worked with a temp branch (cause can't switch to any of the  three branchs) after trying to figure out to exit from the detached head, then  i push the `temp branch` code to all branchs and it works fine using push `HEAD:master` and `HEAD:dev`, now i need to work on origin/dev branch, when running branch -a (i have the remotes/origin/dev, remotes/origin/master, remotes/heroku/master) , but can't chckout the origin master  branch, even after doing git fetch origin.

Comment: Try this: `git checkout dev; git branch -D master; git checkout master`

Comment: thank you , here is the result , 
`Switched to branch 'dev'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/dev'.
error: branch 'master' not found.
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

and `git branch -a ` give `* dev
  temp
  remotes/heroku/master
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/master
`

Comment: can this happen because master name ( branch master for heroku and branch master for origin) ?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered countless times on the site. I know easy rep' is hard to resist, but please try to look for duplicates before posting an answer.

Comment: This is not a correct explanation of a detached head. A detached head is ANY state where `HEAD` points directly to a commit, regardless of where that commit is in the tree. In your diagram, if `HEAD` was pointing to commit 4, it would still be detached, because it is pointing directly to a commit, rather than a branch ref, here, `master`

Comment: This is not a correct explanation of a detached head. A detached head is ANY state where `HEAD` points directly to a commit, regardless of where that commit is in the tree. In your diagram, if `HEAD` was pointing to commit 4, it would still be detached, because it is pointing directly to a commit, rather than a branch ref, here, `master`