# HEAD master ahead of origin/master?

Tags: git

My latest work is in HEAD master and it is ahead of origin/master which are older commits, how to align everything to be in sync thanks

[image: Image of HEAD master ahead of origin/master]

Answer (score 2):

That means you have local commits that aren't pushed. `origin` is usually the remote server. To sync your commits with it, run

```
git push origin master
```

This means "push the branch named `master` on remote server named `origin`".

`git push` is one of the most basic Git commands, if you just started using it, I think you should read a quick guide on how Git works and to familiarize with it a bit.

Comment: I have already done

git add . &&
git commit -m "etc"

which both work fine, but then

git push -u origin master or
git push origin master

I get the indefinite : 
The servers host....If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon connection. Store key in cache(y/n) y. Then when I pressed y nothing happens???

Comment: @niceseb Press "y" then enter to validate.

Comment: Hi @Protectator, Pressed y then enter nothing happens...I tried to reinstall git but says C:\Program Files\Git\ununs001.exe Access is denied?

Answer (score 0):

[`HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2304087/4233593) in your screenshot refers to a local pointer to the most recent commit checked out in your working directory. In this case it's pointing to the same commit that your master tip is pointing to. If you checkout a different branch or individual commit, then you'll see that HEAD pointer move along with it.

`origin/master` points to the commit at the tip of your master branch on the origin remote.

By the looks of your graph, the history appears linear and the origin master is simply behind a couple commits ready for a fast forward merge. The easiest way to push all commits up to the remote and update your local references is

```
git push origin master
```

Now you should see all three pointers `HEAD`, `master`, and `origin/master` pointing to the same commit.