# Numbers in git HEAD

Tags: git, numbers, openembedded

I am compiling Openembedded and at the beginning we can see this :

```
meta-python       = "HEAD:1efa5d623bc64659b57389e50be2568b1355d5f7"
meta-lxde         = "HEAD:9c1501dcb95a8601c8d1fad73c1fcae2886c0377"
meta-browser      = "HEAD:1edcce7791b4cee9a515c1f11b351753a4f8b12e"
meta-qt4          = "HEAD:2c7f8df9039be498f8a2232d1428adb7f4e5e800"
meta-qt5          = "HEAD:9aa870eecf6dc7a87678393bd55b97e21033ab48"
meta-freescale-distro = "HEAD:ae27e8a8a068b960d6c1219f50b2e8ccc97f0bea"
meta-toradex-demos = "HEAD:9fa810182cbb085554ad3a596db6dbf1fc9a0a73"
meta              = "HEAD:c8d96b10ee3bc2eae0fd269d2564286fd0bc82ed"
meta-pjproject    = "<unknown>:<unknown>"
```

The numbers are written in .git/HEAD of each folders. But according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git) it has to be like this :

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

Why is there strange numbers?

Comment: Same question, more detailed answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20465230/1256452 (and more technical, but same point: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18062659/1256452)

Comment: Thank you, so it's "the hash of the most recent commit on the master branch" ? Or the hash from when it was downloaded?

Comment: It's just a specific hash. How OpenEmbedded itself uses them, I have no idea, but this is like telling you to go to the store and get product #1efa5d6, not "any old product that they happen to be calling The Best right now".  Branch names are *moveable* and *expected to move* ("this is the best! no, now THIS is the best!"). Tag names are moveable but not expected to move, and raw hashes identify one specific thing forever.

Comment: Ow, ok thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there strange numbers?

This is build system's way of informing what it is building.

Let's take a look at one of the lines

```
meta-python       = "HEAD:1efa5d623bc64659b57389e50be2568b1355d5f7"
```

When you triggered the build command, I guess `bitbake <some-machine>`, the build system works its way up to the function [base_get_metadata_git_revision](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/classes/metadata_scm.bbclass?h=morty#n75), which runs the git command `git rev-parse HEAD`, thus gets the tip SHA.

In your case, when you got this log your meta-openembedded tip commit was [this one](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/commit/?h=morty&id=1efa5d623bc64659b57389e50be2568b1355d5f7).

Note, that meta-python is a subdir in the meta-openenbedded git, that's the reason you get meta-openembedded SHA for meta-python.