# Is there a character for "current branch" in git?

Tags: git

I need to retype my current branch name constantly.

### Examples

Updating my current branch with the changes from remote

```
git pull origin mySuperLongComplicatedBranchName
```

Push my current branch to remote

```
git push origin mySuperLongComplicatedBranchName
```

---

I would to simplify this to a simple:

```
git pull origin *
```

or something similar. Unless maybe something like this already exists. I'm fairly used to git, but am just hoping I'm missing something simple.

EDIT:

Adding extra info in response to the one comment:

**git show-ref --head**

```
eaadd6401c4e179c105ac3565fe9bf53e2882f83 HEAD 
eaadd6401c4e179c105ac3565fe9bf53e2882f83 refs/heads/myReallyLongBranchName
d6af452b1ad0a309a55061f9eeb6ab7ae83b6aef refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
eaadd6401c4e179c105ac3565fe9bf53e2882f83 refs/remotes/origin/myReallyLongBranchName`
```

so it looks like my remote reallyLongBranch looks identical to current head. Oh I know. I'll

**git fetch**

then I ran

**git show-ref --head again**

```
bc1b96345913e911d03eb62763f8795cc20ecd8f refs/remotes/origin/myReallyLongBranchName
```

Oh great. Now I must be able to do `git pull origin HEAD`.

I run the command. and I get an `Already up to date`.

Then I run:

```
git pull origin mySuperLongComplicatedBranchName
```

I get changes pulled down. Face palm.

It seems as though it doesn't work. Git knows what my current working branch name is... I wish there was just a symbol for it.

Comment: Have you tried not specifying a branch to fetch all?

Answer (score 28):

You can use `HEAD` as "shortcut" for the current commit tree HEAD:

```
git push origin HEAD

git pull origin HEAD
```

`HEAD` usually points to the head commit of currently checked out branch.

**EDIT**: jtill reminded that we have `@` as shortcut for `HEAD`, so it can be even simpler:

```
git push origin @

git pull origin @
```

Comment: What do you mean "usually"? Just want to make sure I know the "gotchas".

Comment: The first (and accepted) answer of this question explains perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git. In general, you are safe to use it :)

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I didn't know to use HEAD. Glad I asked!

Comment: Hmm... An issue I just ran into. `git push origin HEAD` worked. But `git pull origin HEAD` did not. I just got a `Already up-to-date.` message.

Comment: If you do git show-ref --head, the commit id that shows up is for the latest commit from current branch or from master?

Comment: Well, it sounds that git pull origin @ should work fine (because HEAD is pointing to the tip of the current branch indeed). Are you sure that there are changes to be fetched from remote?

Comment: Yep. I outlined my process in my edit. Let me know if you see anything wrong.

Comment: @EGHDK `HEAD` is a valid tag name, so it can refer to any git object.

Comment: `HEAD` is a shorthand for "commit at the tip of the branch" and is absolutely not equivalent to the branch name. It's a commit, and a branch is a pointer to a commit. These are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

These are the shortcuts I use to push and pull, including getting the branch name (not just using HEAD, which points to a commit and will cause issues when pulling):

```
alias push='git push origin "$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)"'
alias pull='git pull origin "$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)"'
```

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer:**

If it's a branch you created, tell git with remote branch you want to track as upstream.

```
git push -u mySuperLongComplicatedBranchName
```

Then just running the command without a remote nor branch name will by default use the upstream branch you're tracking:

```
git pull
```

**Long answer:**

When you publish your branch using `git push`, if it's a branch you created yourself, git asks you to set an upstream branch to be able to **track** changes between your local and remote branches.
This is done by using the `--set-upstream` or the shorter `-u` option.
So `git push origin -u <name_of_your_branch>` publishes (and creates, if it didn't exist) your branch on the `origin` remote.

From `man git-push`:

```
-u, --set-upstream
           For every branch that is up to date or successfully pushed, add upstream (tracking) reference, used by argument-less git-pull(1) and other commands. For more information, see branch.<name>.merge
           in git-config(1).
```

The key info here is: `argument-less git-pull`.

By not specifying either the name of you remote (usually `origin`) nor branch name in your `git pull` command means: "pull from the tracked branch", meaning the one you defined as upstream.

So just running `git pull` to merge changes on the upstream branch or `git pull -r` to rebase your branch on the remote changes is what you're looking for.