# What is the default stuff shown when I do git branch -r

Tags: git, github

I created a blank repo in github. It gets named as master.

In my local machine I did a git init and git clone of this repo.

Now when I do `git branch -r` I see

```
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

From reading numerous articles and post my understanding is the following:
`origin/HEAD -> origin/master`
In above line `origin/HEAD` means currently checkout branch and `-> origin/master` means that it is pointed to master branch in remote (origin/ meaning remote)

However I think I might be thinking wrong, since I also read anything with `origin/` to it represents remote since `origin/` means remote.

So what is going on here, I am lost :(

Also why is there a second line saying `origin/master` again?

I read so many many posts and answers in SO and other sites but I am unable to make sense of this. Can any git gurus help me out here?

Comment: Run `git branch` *without* `-r`, or with `-a` (for "all"). Pay less attention to anything named `origin/<whatever>` since those are just your Git's way of remembering some *other* Git's branches.

Comment: Other than that, the place to start is with a good book on Git. There is a lot to learn!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git branch -r` asks the question, "What remote branches do I know about?"

You're correct that `origin/` represents a remote reference here, but it's just *one* remote reference--namely the repo from which you cloned your local repository. If you want to see other remotes you know about and where they point, run a `git remote -v`.

Focusing on just `origin/master` for a moment, this means that you know about a remote (named `origin`) that has a branch on it called `master`. You can even see commits on it if you do something like `git log origin/master`.

The first line `origin/HEAD -> origin/master` is a bit more complex, but means that, last you checked, the remote `origin` has the `master` branch checked out. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git) for more discussion on what the HEAD pointer is.