# Is there one or more Git HEAD?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm actually trying to deep dive into the core concepts of Git. And recently I was interested by the **HEAD** pointer of **Git**.

I understand that HEAD is a pointer that is pointing to a branch (and indirectly to a commit) or directly to a commit. This is the difference between attached and detached HEAD if my understanding is correct. This topic help me to clear the majority of questions that I have on this subject : [What is HEAD in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-head-in-git)

But one question that I dont have found the answer remain.

If I am on a branch A and I checkout to a past commit, I have then a detached HEAD on this commit. If I checkout to a branch B then, the HEAD is on the last commit of this branch. And if I'm go back on branch A, it seems that the HEAD are still on the past commit I have reached before.

So I was wondering : Does it exists one and only HEAD pointer that keep track of his previous position on each branch OR does it exists multiples HEAD pointer for multiple branches ?

I have made multiples move on a Git project to understand the behaviour and check multiples Stack Overflow questions and articles on the web to theorically understand the concept of HEAD. But I don't found any clear answer to my question.

Comment: Think about (or read up on) where the information about `HEAD` is stored and the answer will become obvious. The internal structure of a git repository is not quite as obscure as it might look at first glance. (Also be aware that "a git head" and "the git HEAD" are quite different).

Comment: "*And if I'm go back on branch A, it seems that the HEAD are still on the past commit I have reached before.*" If you do that, `HEAD` points to `A`'s last commit, **not** to the old commit you checked out directly a bit earlier. Double check your tests, it might just be a mistake in your observations.

Comment: I have checked for the .git folder and the HEAD file have actual reference to the refs folder that seems to have multiples references for each branch.  But it seems to have reference to the last commit id of each branch if I watched correctly. So I understand that there is only one HEAD pointer that reach the references when we travel from one branch to another for me.

Comment: The `HEAD` can point to a branch which in turn points to a commit. A branch is just a pointer to a specific commit.

Answer (score 2):

There's only a single `HEAD` symbolic ref per repository (or per [*worktree*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) if you are using that feature). The target of the symbolic ref is stored in file `.git/HEAD`. (There's only a single file with a single line, so there can only be a single `HEAD`).

This is what it looks like if you have checked out branch `master` at the moment:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master
```

In *detached HEAD* state, it will look like this:

```
$ cat .git/HEAD
0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567
```

Comment: Each worktree has its own `HEAD`. So a repository has as many of them as it has worktrees.

Comment: @Guildenstern good point, thanks. I will clarify

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is only one `HEAD`.[1] And your understanding of how `HEAD`
works and how branches (which are `refs/heads/*` refs) work is correct.

If you do things like `git checkout <branch>` and `git checkout <SHA1>`
then this is all there is to it. There is no need to remember anything.

But you might also use special [revision syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) like:

```
# Where `HEAD` was five moves ago
git checkout HEAD@{5}
# Where `HEAD` was at that time
git checkout HEAD@{5.minutes.ago}
# Where `HEAD` was last (like `cd -`)
git checkout -
```

What Git is using in this case is a *reflog*, which is a log (one line per
entry) of where that ref has been. This will be updated for example every
time you do a `git checkout` or every time you do `git reset <mode> <commitish>`.

So Git will remember where `HEAD` was for you if the reflog is enabled.

And the reflog will also remember the same thing for branches:

```
git checkout main@{5}
git checkout main@{5.minutes.ago}
```

Because each branch gets its own reflog in the same way that `HEAD` has
its own reflog.

And you can also log other kinds of ref moves if you have set
`core.logAllRefUpdates` to `true`.

#### Notes

1. Each Git worktree has its own `HEAD` but if you don't know what that is
   then it doesn't matter in any case