# HEAD detached at origin/master

Tags: git

I've just checked out an old project to fix a bug. git reports:

```
HEAD detached at origin/master
```

`git status` reports I have an untracked file:

```
<project name>.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/
```

I'd like to get on and fix the bug but I'm not sure quite what's going on. If I try `git checkout master` I get:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
<project name>.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/
```

Can I just delete this file? Am I on the `master` branch? If not, how do I get to it?

Comment: Is the provided untracked directory vital for your project? Or don't you know where it came from?

Comment: The line `git status` shows you, will be created everytime you have `xCode` opened. Think this changes everytime you switch a window in xCode so make sure you quit xCode before doing any changes.  ( add it to .gitignore file )

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As [CommuSoft says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25232069/1256452), you're not on master.  You're in "detached HEAD" mode.  You get that any time you explicitly check out something that is not a (local) branch name:

```
$ git checkout origin/master    # detach to "remote branch"
```

or if there's a tag `v1.7`:

```
$ git checkout v1.7             # detach to tag
```

and you can even explicitly detach when using a local branch name:

```
$ git checkout --detach master  # forcibly detach
```

A "detached HEAD" means you're not on a branch.  Being "on a branch" means you're not using the detached HEAD mode.  Yes, that's pretty circular; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21054148/1256452) and its answers for more details.

As for the:

> `error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten ...`

When you get `git checkout` to move from one commit to another, it does two main things:

1. choose whether to be in "detached HEAD" mode, and
2. rearrange the work tree to match the moved-to commit.

Step 2 is where the problem is occurring.  You're on the commit identified by `origin/master`, and in that commit, there is no record of the files git is currently complaining about.  You've asked to switch to the commit identified by `master`, which is obviously a different commit.<sup>1</sup>  Git sees that in the commit identified by `master`, there *are* some (maybe just one) files with the same names, that are *different* from the files or directories that are in your work-tree right now.

In order to switch from the current commit to the new one, `git checkout` must remove the existing files-or-directories and replace them with the ones in the new commit—the one you're asking to switch to.  If those files or directories were tracked in the current commit, git would be happy to remove and replace them as needed, as git can always get them back for you: just switch back to that old commit, and there they are.  But they're *not* in the current, to-be-switched-away-from, commit.  So git tells you: "Hey, if I make this switch you asked for, I can't guarantee that I'll be able to restore these files and/or directories."

It's now up to *you*, not git, to figure out what to do with these files and/or directories.  Based on the error message, it's a directory,<sup>2</sup> and switching to `master` will cause that directory to be removed and replaced with something else (possibly a different directory with some file(s) in it, possibly just a file).  Do you:

- want to save it/them?
- if so, do you want to save it/them in a commit, or just move them out of the way?
- or do you just want to blow them away?

To save them, either commit them, or move them out of the way (e.g., rename them to a path that's not part of the work-tree, or to a different untracked name that's "safer", whatever that would be).

To simply blow them away, remove them manually or use `git checkout -f` (force) to make git do it.

Since you're not on a branch now (are in "detached HEAD" mode), if you want to commit them permanently to the repository, you can use something like the method CommuSoft added while I was writing this up.  (You can create the new branch at any time, before or after doing a "git commit".)

You can also use `git stash`.  Git's `stash` is deceptively complex little script: it makes commits that are not on any branch at all, that can later be transplanted to a branch.  Using it is quite simple and easy: you just run `git stash save` and all pending tracked changes are saved and cleaned up, or run `git stash save -u` and all pending tracked changes *and* untracked files are saved and cleaned up.  They are now all safely squirreled away in the repository, under a commit, even though it's not a commit-on-a-branch.

There is no single right answer for what to do here.

---

<sup>1</sup>Obviously different, because if you were already on the commit you're asking git to move *to*, then either the file would be in the commit and hence tracked, or it would be not-in-the-commit and hence you would not be asking git to clobber it.

<sup>2</sup>This is a little odd.  If I make a directory that will be clobbered by my `git checkout`, and I make it as an *empty* directory, git just goes ahead and clobbers it.  Here the difference between `master^` and `master` is that moving forward from `master^` to `master` creates file `mxgroup.py` (so stepping back removes it):

```
$ git checkout -q master^  # file goes away, now let's mkdir...
$ mkdir mxgroup.py; git checkout -q master
$ file mxgroup.py
mxgroup.py: Python script, ASCII text executable
```

However, if I have a non-empty directory, I get a different error message:

```
$ git checkout -q master^  # file goes away; mkdir and make file
$ mkdir mxgroup.py; touch mxgroup.py/file; git checkout -q master
error: Updating the following directories would lose untracked files in it:
    mxgroup.py

Aborting
```

But this is with git version 2.0.2; perhaps older gits are not as clever.

Comment: The linked problem was very helpful. I was looking for an answer to why checking out a branch on remote puts me in detached head. The answer is doing `git checkout origin/master` puts you at a specific revision, whereas `git checkout master` will resolve to `git checkout -b master --track origin/master` as [documented here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt).

Comment: @young_souvlaki: Right. Note that the new (in Git 2.23) `git switch` will tell you that `origin/master` is not a *branch* name and thus can only be checked out with the `--detach` option. The old `git checkout` assumes you understand this already, and hence inserts `--detach` for you. The old `checkout` tries the name as a branch name (and as DWIM mode, though sometimes too late!) but if that fails, proceeds to try it as pathspec and via `git rev-parse` and will overwrite files or do a detached HEAD checkout correspondingly.

Comment: These rules are overly complex and sometimes surprise even experienced Git users. If you have Git 2.23 or later, it's probably wise to retrain yourself to use `git switch` for branch checkout, and `git restore` for file checkout. (I still haven't quite done this myself.)

Answer (score 27):

No you're not on the master branch, your on some kind of "newly invented" branch without a name that was once the master.

You simply need to switch back to the master:

```
git checkout master
```

However if you wish to fix a bug, you should work at your own branch (according to most git workflows). Thus checkout the master and branch from it:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b fix-issue #give the branch a name that refers to the bug
```

then fix the bug and run:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff fix-issue -m "Fixed some strange issue, here follows a description"
```

---

**EDIT**

As specified in your question you have an untracked file. If these file(s) are of no importance, you can remove them. If on the other hand you wish to maintain them, you can merge them into the master first.

Therefore you create a temporary branch:

```
git commit -m "some temporary message"
git checkout -b temporary
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff temporary
```

Comment: the explanation is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

> I was facing the same issue.

I was checking out origin branch directly from local which was wrong-

```
git checkout origin/dev_branch
```

Ideally I should fetch origin branches on local and then check out required branch as below-

```
git fetch
```

then

```
git checkout dev_branch
```

This approach worked for me, Hope will help you too!!!