# Why I see 'HEAD detached from' when I git status?

Tags: git, gitlab

I tried to switch to another commit, so I did  :  `git checkout 031c057` (fourth commit in order)

After I switched back to  `a06bbac` then I did some modification and I did a 'commit'

Now when I `git status` I see  :

```
$ git status
HEAD detached from a06bbac
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Here my git log  :

```
f24cb85 (HEAD) seconde template
a06bbac (mostafa-test) sc just for test
19c2ad5 (origin/mostafa-test) first sample template
031c057 sc
f6c72a0 make component for table and header
89a0dd3 material-table ready
748ce3b first grid & first table
605562f (master) git ignore fix
1ec70f4 sc
eadfa97 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Initial commit
```

How to make it normal ?

Comment: Don't use raw commit IDs with `checkout`; use existing branch heads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HEAD detached at origin/master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232056/head-detached-at-origin-master)

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987957/how-did-i-end-up-with-a-detached-head/34994175#34994175

Comment: @jub0bs Yes Thanks it works

Comment: I did the same thing. I solved the problem by checking out my changes on a new branch, switching to the main branch, and then merging the changes from the new branch.

Answer (score 3):

`HEAD` is a special *symbolic* reference. It's meant to refer to branch heads, not commits directly. When it refers to something that *isn't* a branch head, we say that `HEAD` is in a detached state.

After you ran `git checkout a06bbac`, your Git state resembled

```
HEAD ----------------> a06bbac ---> 19c2ad5 ---> ...
                         ^
                         |
mostafa-test ------------+
```

rather than

```
HEAD ----> mostafa-test --> a06bbac ---> 19c2ad5 ---> ...
```

As a result, running `git commit` did not update `mostafa-test` as it should have.

To fix this, you can simply checkout `mostafa-test`, then use `git reset` to fix it.

```
$ git checkout mostafa-test
$ git reset f24cb85
```

Comment: Thanks , I did it but the changes I did in commit  `f24cb85 (HEAD) seconde template` are not applied !

Is it possible to "merge" this commit to my current branch ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. `f24cb85` already has `a06bbac` as its parent; the only problem is that it isn't correctly identified as the branch head `mostafa-test`. What does `git log --graph --online --all --decorate` show?

Comment: I did the exact same thing as the OP and tried your procedure, but I lost my changes. Fortunately, I copied my repo to a new directory before attempting this and so restored it without having to do git magic. I solved the problem by checking out my changes on a new branch, switching to the main branch, and then merging the changes from the new branch.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found It  :

First I kept my commit by : `git branch -f mostafa-test HEAD

Then : `git checkout mostafa-test`

It seems working !

Answer (score 0):

It means HEAD is detached from a branch.

So when come back to `a06bbac`, use `git checkout mostafa-test`.

Normally HEAD is on a branch, not commit.

Comment: Tanks , but when I do this I lose all modification I did in commit `f24cb85`and it returns to  commit `a06bbac` , How to keep the commit `f24cb85`