# git checkout refs/heads/master detaches HEAD

Tags: git, git-detached-head

I have a local branch "master" tracking a remote branch "origin/master".

When I checkout master like this:

```
git checkout refs/heads/master
```

I end up with a detached HEAD:

> Note: checking out 'refs/heads/master'.
>
> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
>   changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
>   state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

Obviously I could just checkout "master", but that happens to be an ambiguous reference. I just want to know what the "git way" to disambiguate a branch name is, without detaching HEAD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: refname 'master' is ambiguous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224773/git-refname-master-is-ambiguous)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. My question is not about the warning itself (that's quite clear). It's just about the detached HEAD state after checking out refs/heads/master. (I'll edit the question to clarify.)

Comment: What do you mean with "disambiguate a branch name without detaching HEAD"?, what is the expected result ?

Comment: In a really generic context (i.e. you don't know about existing tags or other references that might conflict with the branch name master), **how do I checkout the branch master without any ambiguity**? I can _not_ checkout refs/heads/master, which would be the most logical thing in my eyes, because that detaches HEAD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does \`git checkout\` with explicit 'refs/heads/branch' give detached HEAD?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21054148/why-does-git-checkout-with-explicit-refs-heads-branch-give-detached-head)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `git checkout` is silent on how it behaves when `master` is ambiguous.  Looking at the source code (I skimmed quickly so I might be wrong), it looks like `git checkout` assumes that the provided name (e.g., `master`) is a branch name until it discovers that there is no ref in `refs/heads/*` for the given name.

So the proper way to check out a branch when the revision is ambiguous is to leave off the `refs/heads/`, e.g., `git checkout master`.

#### Branch vs. revision

Note that there is a subtle but important difference between specifying a *branch* and specifying a *revision* (or other *object*).  For commands and options that take a revision (or general object), specifying `master` is the same as specifying `refs/heads/master` unless `master` is ambiguous.  It's also the same as specifying `master^0`, or the SHA1 that `master` is pointing to, etc.

For commands and options that take a branch (e.g., `git branch`, or the `--branches` option to commands like `git log`), specifying `master` is not the same as specifying `refs/heads/master`.  In these cases, the full string `refs/heads/master` is interpreted as the name of the branch, causing Git to create/examine/update the ref named `refs/heads/refs/heads/master` instead of `refs/heads/master`.

The `git checkout` command is versatile, which is handy but can cause confusion in cases like `master` vs. `refs/heads/master`.  When you specify `master`, and a ref named `refs/heads/master` exists, `git checkout` assumes you meant the `master` branch, not the revision that `master` is pointing to.  When you specify `refs/heads/master`, and a ref named `refs/heads/refs/heads/master` does not exist, then `git checkout` assumes you meant the revision that `master` is pointing to, not a branch named `refs/heads/master` (thus you get a detached `HEAD`).

#### Checking out the non-branch when ambiguous

If you want to check out some other ref whose short name is also `master` (e.g. a tag named `master`), you'll have to spell out the full ref name (e.g., `git checkout refs/tags/master`) or spell the revision in a way that can't be interpreted as a valid branch name (e.g., `git checkout master^0`).  The latter causes `git checkout` to follow the disambiguation rules described in `git help revisions`:

> When ambiguous, a `<refname>` is disambiguated by taking the first match in the following rules:
>
> 1. If `$GIT_DIR/<refname>` exists, that is what you mean (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
> 2. otherwise, `refs/<refname>` if it exists;
> 3. otherwise, `refs/tags/<refname>` if it exists;
> 4. otherwise, `refs/heads/<refname>` if it exists;
> 5. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>` if it exists;
> 6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

Of course the result will be a detached `HEAD`, but that always happens when you check out a non-branch.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the point about git's behaviour in the ambiguous case. I have no objection to git detaching HEAD when I actually checkout a non-branch, but refs/heads/master is arguably a branch, regardless of how I reference it, isn't it?

Comment: @Jan:  I added some paragraphs to hopefully answer your question.

Comment: This should be in the git documentation. Thanks! Though I think the warning about an ambiguous reference is bogus when you can't actually disambiguate further.