# Node.js package for extracting branch name from git ref

Tags: node.js, npm, github-actions

I am running my CI on GitHub Actions, and I am using the [GITHUB_REF](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) default environment variable as a part of a download URL.

GitHub sets the `GITHUB_REF` to:

```
refs/heads/staging
```

I understand from [git: difference between "branchname" and "refs/heads/branchname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526471/git-difference-between-branchname-and-refs-heads-branchname) that the `refs/heads/` prefix is needed so that git has the "full path" to the branch.

Now, I am wondering if anyone knows of an off-the-shelf node.js package deployed to a registry like [npmjs](https://www.npmjs.com) that I could use to extract the branch name from the long ref string? It seems like there could be many different prefixes: `refs/tags/`, `refs/remotes`, etc., and I would prefer not to write my custom script if there is another solution available.

Comment: `$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Lawrence Cherone's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167493/node-js-package-for-extracting-branch-name-from-git-ref?noredirect=1#comment122249328_69167493), I found this [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/wosephjeber/212f0ca7fea740c3a8b03fc2283678d3):

```js
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

function executeGitCommand(command) {
  return execSync(command)
    .toString('utf8')
    .replace(/[\n\r\s]+$/, '');
}

const BRANCH = executeGitCommand('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD');
const COMMIT_SHA = executeGitCommand('git rev-parse HEAD');
```

It's not an npm package but it is good enough for now.